# Should Zero-Voted Questions and Deleted Questions determine Question Banning

Tags: discussion, zero-voted-posts

I read a few posts on question banning based on zero-voted questions and questions that longed been deleted. Made me wonder why should such make one in "danger of being banned"(this is what I am reading now when I was about to ask a question) especially if he/she just made like 10 question posts in the life-cycle of his/her account.

If we delete questions that were downvoted then that "keeps the quality of your sites high" No crappy questions are located on the website to deter good questions. To me it is like a forever punishment "saying hey idiot crappy question, you don't belong on this site so go somewhere else and don't come back flooding our site with stupid questions"   Or sometimes I feel like they saying "don't delete the downvoted questions because I want everyone to see how stupid you really are." Oh well I guess that's the end of my questioning.

I wonder if anybody else feels this way.

Comment: see also: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Answer (score 12):

It is good that deleted posts count towards rate-limiting and an eventual ban.

Otherwise, what's to stop someone to just try throwing stuff at SO and see what sticks? If deleted posts did not count, they could just delete what did not stick (i.e. what was not well received by the community) and continue like this forever.

Comment: And I am not understanding what is wrong with this. Some posts people think are fine but people are so quick (like this post) to downvote okay so delete it and then try to make a  better one. I think this rule makes people not want to ask questions like in a classroom.

Comment: What's wrong is that people who ask terrible questions (as evidenced by the multiple downvotes they are receiving) are wasting *everybody's* time. SO has tried as best as possible to optimize the site so that *experts* are willing to hang around and answer questions. If you waste their time, the experts are not going to stay.

Comment: @Rika It makes people not want to ask *bad* questions.  The fact that great questions tend to attract extremely high quality questions extremely quickly means that there are very strong incentives to ask *good* questions.  Incentivising very good questions and discouraging bad questions is *the goal*.  Incentivizing any and all questions, regardless of quality, is most certainly *not* what we want.  Many other sites have tired that; it doesn't end well.

Comment: @Louis SO this is site for experts/researchers only and not for beginners or intermediates for if you ask a question you wasting everyone's time (like 10 seconds) Thanks for the input that was really helpful. Just forget it I want contribute anymore, I guess people like this type of     I don't.

Comment: @Rika The site would be flooded with low-quality questions that haven't been deleted *yet*. We've seen people ask the same question every 30 minutes until they get an answer they like, then delete the old ones. This is not a good use of the community's time.

Comment: @BilltheLizard then it will be good to target really those people in another way except hurting other beginners and intermediates who don't do that

Comment: @Rika Question banning does target people who ask a lot of low-quality questions, including those that need to be deleted.

Comment: @Rika You *aren't* hurt by the question ban if you're actually asking quality questions, or if you're able to learn from a few mistakes and begin providing quality contributions when you are informed that your contributions aren't up to par.

Comment: @Servy But I am targeted like my question post said,  I am seeing "Wait you are in danger being banned" And I had about 7 question posts now online and probably deleted 3 questions if that like in the lifecycle of my account

Comment: @Rika You are being warned that if you perform sufficient undesirable actions that there will be consequences.  These warnings are there to allow you to avoid making mistakes in the first place, and to improve the quality of your contributions rather than trying to hide them.  Many people seem to think that they can just sweep all of their problems under the rug and they'll go away forever; the warning is telling you that that won't happen.  You will be judged on all of your contributions, even the ones you try to hide.

Comment: @Rika also, the 7 questions I can see on your account have a total vote count of -1. If we assume the deleted ones are also at a negative total, then yes, I think that would put you at risk.  We are not trying to stop YOU from asking questions. We are trying to filter for GOOD questions. Use the feedback on your questions to improve them, and you'll see the ban warning will go away.  Before asking, make sure you search, you google, you search stack, you google again, you look the language's specs, you google again, then ask your question. If it's a "newbie" question, it's been asked somewhere.

Comment: @Patrice Maam I really do a lot of searching and most questions I have don't get posted because I search before I ask. But it seems it really doesn't matter if you have 6 neutral questions(zero-voted) and 1 negative voted question. Doesn't seem like a GOOD way to filter GOOD questions.

Comment: @Rika I'm french, Patrice is masculine :P.  In any case, yes. You have 7 questions, not ONE of them was qualified "good" by the community. So if in 7 questions you NEVER got a good question.... yes, I do believe stopping bad questions from arriving is a good way to get better questions on the site.

Answer (score 7):

The idea behind the ban is to make the person **think** before hitting submit.

This is because anytime someone asks a question, they consume resources.

- Any person who visits the question could have visited another question if that person did not post the question
- Anyone who helped vote, edit, comment, and/or moderate that question could have spent time helping moderate another question
- Anyone who starting writing an answer, or researching the issue to provide an answer could have spent their time answering another question.

Effectively deleting a question (any question whether good or bad) just wasted everyone's time.  You do it once or twice, that's fine.  You learn and move one.  But if someone refuses to learn from their mistakes and continually wastes everyone's time by posting a poor quality question needs to be rate limited in some fashion.

This is what the question ban it... it is the ultimate rate limiter.  Someone is stopped to keep them from posting poor quality content until they can demonstrate that they understand how to use the site correctly and how to provide good quality content.

Comment: I just put about like 10 question posts. Like ever since I signed up. Most were 0 voted. To me this "ultimate rate limiter" is too picky. And I believe I have a right to an opinion

Comment: @Rika You *absolutely* have the right to your opinion.  But so does everyone else.  You don't have the right to force your opinion on everyone else, merely to have it.

Comment: What do you mean force, why do people always say that when you don't agree with them or you decide not to step down from your opinion

Comment: @Rika Why are you saying, "I believe I have a right to an opinion" just because somebody disagreed with your opinion?  Who was ever prohibiting you from having an opinion to cause you to say that?

Comment: This, ladies and gentlemen, is why we don't do opinions on Stack Overflow proper.

Comment: @Servy What are you talking about I said that so nobody wouldn't have to come back talking "why I am sooo wrong"