# Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban, bad-questions

We are told

> The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, but users are only banned if they have a significant number of ... deleted posts.

I'm only starting here, and I know I'll (hopefully) get better.  But when someone with astronomic levels of reputation swoops in to point out how pathetic my efforts at phrasing a proper question are, I have a tendency to want to burn my efforts and start again.  I have done this a few times, voluntarily removing questions that I didn't know would cause confusion, to avoid the endless stream of off-the-point answers and comments, not to mind downvotes, that I have caused through my inadequacy.

I know I should just get better at asking questions. I'm just getting more and more afraid of spending an hour researching a question to have it marked as a duplicate or worse within seconds of putting it up.

Before I do, what I want to know is this: should I discontinue my practice of scrapping and restarting questions to avoid the ban algorithm, or should I leave my pathetic scraps to be feasted on by downvotes and irate comments?

Comment: Don't know - you deleted the evidence.

Comment: I can't imagine that voluntary deletions should count towards the question ban.

Comment: Maybe SO just isn't the right place for you to contribute.  It's not for everybody and doesn't try to be.

Comment: You can edit your question whilst deleted and undelete it. You don't have to post a new one.

Comment: "Perhaps I should give in to this Darwinian selection and piss off back to being a musician" Asking duplicate questions on Stack Overflow is not really indicative of failure at learning how to program, if that's what you're saying. Although, if you're new to programming, SO is usually not the right place to start.

Comment: "users are only banned if they have a significant number of ... deleted posts" Who told you that?

Comment: [Nooble](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3886129), is that you?

Comment: Sorry folks, having a bad day.  I'm not new to programming, I'm just new to the branch of programming that I am using SO for.  I am very good at finding my own answers and only come on here when I am stuck.  I look for things I can help with, and find some, but some of you are just so DAMN FAST!  So I'm usually frustrated already when I come on here, and being slapped down, however justifiably, doesn't help. Turns out I can delete my worse questions without penalty after 30 days (although that doesn't help with the banning algorithm).

Comment: @Yannis I edited a sentence from here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans (notice my ellipsis)

Comment: @Everybody Never mind, all my future posts are going to be IMPECCABLE.  They might even last a few seconds before I have to start the campaign to get them unflagged as duplicates because my phrasing has been too subtle for the experts :-) Be happy people.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå No.

Comment: As an aside, if you are having trouble finding duplicates, check out the [Advanced Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). Being able to get results of only questions in specific tags is very helpful as well as some of the other options.

Comment: @BSMP Thank you, I was having a bad head day yesterday (THEN STAY AWAY FROM FORUMS REG!) and it's nice to have somebody offer encouraging constructive advice on using the site.  I'm just having a few teething problems with the community style.

Comment: I'm late to the table, but these are *not* forums. If you think, even subconsciously, of SO as a "forum", you'll have trouble contributing good content...

Comment: @KubaOber I was referring to the Meta, which is a clearly meant to be a forum for discussion [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).  I was concerned with Java at the time I wrote the post above, and found the community very belligerent in that topic. Now I am more concerned with Android and the more tolerant atmosphere there (which I need less as I am no longer a noob) makes it like a different universe.  Mind you, it seems I still feel the effects of the original Java-area treatment as I am active on many other sites, but do not help out at all on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Whether a post was deleted is mostly irrelevant to the question ban.** If someone tells you otherwise, tell them they're wrong; if you see a meta post that says otherwise, edit it.

What matters are *poorly-received* posts. That is, questions that are downvoted, closed, or flagged as inappropriate in some way. These can all result in post bans and *also* all result in the post being deleted, but saying deletion is to blame for most post bans is akin to saying that hospitals are to blame for most diseases.

The *one* exception involves deleting a question right after someone posts an answer to it. This (fairly rare!) pattern is seen as so overtly hostile that it does impose a pretty stiff penalty... But that's also a far cry from "self-censoring".

Where folks usually trip up is in thinking that if they delete all their crappy questions the system won't *notice* that they're bad at asking... But the system doesn't care whether the posts are deleted or not; if you asked a dozen questions and they were all badly-received, you're probably question banned - the only difference deletion makes is that you can't *fix* a deleted question.

Comment: In fact, hospitals *are* to blame for many diseases. Nosocomial infections cause or contribute to nearly 100,000 deaths per year in the United States. (My hobby: nitpicking analogies.)

Comment: I've always read this post of yours as "zero-score posts don't matter in a question ban". But [this new meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351820/what-can-be-improved-with-my-questions-to-prevent-0-votes) suggests otherwise. Is that OP hiding some downvoted questions up their sleeve, or can zero-voted questions indeed lead to a question ban? (Sorry for the somewhat spammy comment)

Comment: If you ask 100 questions, with 50 scoring -1 and 50 scoring 1, your average is 0 @AndrasDeak. If you ask 100 questions with 50 scoring -1 and 50 that no one has voted on, your average is -0.5 - but the average score of posts that have been voted on is -1, so you really shouldn't be patting yourself on the back too hard about the 50% of questions no one cared about at all. As far as the ban is concerned, you're not gonna get banned because of zero-scored posts (rate-limited maybe; rate-limit doesn't care about score at all).

Comment: OK, thanks, awesome. In the mean time I found in a comment that some of OP's 0-score questions are not 0-*vote*. My concern was that perhaps voteless posts can lead to bans, which would be awful and counter-intuitive. I'm glad it's not the case, thanks for clarifying! And thanks for chiming in on the other post.

Comment: Shog, would you mind editing [ban faq at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/165773) to get more in line with your explanation here (there is stuff like "deleted answers always count towards an automatic ban on new accounts" etc). I regularly see complaints about that it says things differently but when I finally decided to edit it today I discovered that I can't do that because it is locked

Comment: Embarrassingly, *I* phrased that line @gnat; edited to make it clear that it pertains to answer-bans.

Comment: "This (fairly rare!) pattern" - if only it were so. It's common enough IMX for rep-seeking FGITWs to answer terrible questions that shouldn't have been asked in the first place, before the OP can even receive the feedback about why the question is terrible (or read the code for the N+1th time and finally notice the typo).

Answer (score 6):

Deleted questions count towards a ban just as much as questions that are not deleted. If you have a lot of poorly received or unanswered questions and you delete them, you are just creating a reservoir of questions that can never be either answered or upvoted.

Instead of scrapping a question

1. Spend more time researching it and polishing it before pressing the Submit button so you don't have to scrap it at all. You may find the answer without even having to ask the question at all.
2. If you do need to rewrite it you can always delete it temporarily, compose the replacement text in another question that you aren't going to submit and then undelete and replace the original question text. Be careful not to invalidate any existing answers if you do this.

On the face of it deleting questions, would not seem to put you in a position where you're less likely to be banned. If they are not terrible i.e. 0 score and you leave them alone, someone might come across them and answer them. If they do get answers, they may then start to get upvotes as they would be more useful from that point on. If they have 0 votes, that may be all that's holding them back at the moment.

Comment: Is this true, can we really just take the old frame of a deleted question and re-use it in a completely new topic in title and body? Would that not be against the logic of the ban process? It would be too easy to get out of your ban if you just use old deleted questions for a new question.

Comment: Not if it has answers. You might get away with it if it doesn't. It's certainly frowned upon.

Comment: Still - very interesting. Since they all have just my own answers (self-answered). That would be the solution for me. I will just try as soon as I have a good answer at hand.

Comment: My answer was talking about rewriting a question without invalidating answers. I.e. making it say what you really intended. If you ask a completely different question you may well find it gets downvoted and deleted.

Comment: I simply need to delete my answers then, and that would only risk a ban on my answers, which is unlikely. I will just try it, better than waiting for six months. I will wait for a good question and drop a comment here if it worked. Because that would be quite a good trick.

Comment: Being suspended because you [knew it was wrong and did it anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066/drastic-question-revision) is the risk you're taking here. I really would advise against that course of action.

Comment: I did not know it was wrong, now that you are saying it I know - and only if you are right here? Which is not 100% for sure. Thank you for the link.

Comment: "It would be too easy to get out of your ban if you just use old deleted questions for a new question" - not really. First off, if noticed, a drastic change to the question could be punished manually as an abuse of the system. Second, the undeleted question would still have the old downvotes attached.