# Should posters be able to single handedly close their own post?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128045/bundle-xxxcontroller-does-not-exist-or-it-is-not-enabled) which was something I had been trying to fix for a while. 40 minutes after I post my question, I realize that the solution was just a simple typo.

I could delete my question, however I figured it would be better to simply self-close my question as off topic.

It however still needs more close votes.

Shouldn't I be able to single handedly close my own question?

Comment: No one (except diamond moderators) is allowed to single-handedly close a post except as a duplicate. If it was a simple typo and you have an otherwise good history, and you haven't received answers, then deleting it isn't a big deal. By voting to close your own post it'd have put it in the CV review queue, and if the community agree with you, it'll be closed soon enough. However, you may be denying answers of the type "You've got a typo here - but on line xyz you're also going to get a bug because... etc..."

Comment: In this case - I've closed the question as a typo anyway - as it's very specific.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for closing, though I don't find the downvote from whomever to be really fair. Makes me just want to delete the question.

Comment: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Comment: @gnat thanks. Does that mean I should just delete it?

Comment: per my reading, it means just that

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think if a question has no answers from anyone apart from the “asker”, then it should be possible for the “asker” to close the question on their own.

The reasons we don’t allow people to close their own questions, is that they are considered to be owned by everyone, but if no-one else has contributed, is this true?

Comment: Allowing him to delete, sure. Though he can always go the long way. Allowing him to close, not so much.

Comment: @Deduplicator, what if he is closing as a duplicate that he found based on someone's comment?

Comment: Maybe what is needed is just LESS votes from other people if the "asker" has voted to close.

Comment: Sure, the asker gets to vote if he has at least 250 rep. And anyway, he can single-handedly close as dupe if he has 50: Flag for dupe, accept the suggestion.

Comment: I agree with you in that I don't see any reason to disallow closure of an unanswered question, but I also don't see the point of the feature: having decided the question is not worthwhile, the user may as well just remove it entirely.