# Why does it still take 5 votes to close your own post?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

I asked a question (actually 2), that I later figured out were caused by simple typographic errors. I don't want to delete the posts (although I did one), as they were harder to track down than just typing an l (L) instead of 1.

I am trying to close one, and I don't see why I can't just close it myself, especially since it has an accepted answer (which is my own). I saw this question: [Should posters be able to single handedly close their own post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315931/should-posters-be-able-to-single-handedly-close-their-own-post), where there was 1 answer which did not really answer my question: why can't I close my own post? The question in that post is the same, the answer does not answer my question. Seeing as it was only active nearly 2 years ago, I thought I'd ask again.

Should posters be able to single-handedly close their own posts?

Comment: Better question: _"Why does it still take 5 votes to close any post?"_ :)

Comment: I was waiting for this very interesting question. How come I can't close my OWN question when I know they deserve closure. That is, while I can't delete them because they've been upvoted

Comment: The arguments in the duplicate seem to make sense.  Closure is usually the first step to either fixing, or deletion.  If it's your own, and you can delete...what's the problem?

Comment: @fbueckert That's exactly THE problem, I want to delete it but i can't !!!

Comment: If someone votes to close your question as a duplicate you should get a notification on the question. You can accept that notification and the community user will close the question as a duplicate. it does rely on someone else spotting the duplicate first though.

Comment: Once you have an upvoted answer, @Antoine, the question requires more than your judgement; deletion in that case wastes the effort of the answerer; something we try not to do.  You shouldn't be able to delete in that case.

Comment: @fbueckert When the question is closed, does it falls in a process where many people can judge the question ? If yes then all's good... no ?

Comment: A review queue?  I don't think so.  But anyone at 10k or higher can vote to delete after being closed for two days.  20k don't even need to wait that long.  Thing is, though, what argument is there to close your own question, instead of deleting it?  If you can't delete it, why should you be able to close it, @Antoine?

Comment: Because as the author of the question, you sometimes realize that things got out of hand. You needed something that you are not going to obtain in an answer. This make the question useless for other user, even for the asker. The answerer should not have even answered the question because (and I have an exemple) because what was asked cannot be answered in text. It takes way more than a simple answer. When the asker (it happened to me) gets better, he then look back at his question and be like : "ho wait... what was I thinking"

Comment: But the question have long been forgotten before you realise it... so it is to me... A "zombi" question

Comment: I don't buy that the question was useless for anybody else; after all, the answer, at least got an upvote.  So not only did somebody take the time to answer, somebody else found it useful.  There's plenty of evidence to show that curators are overworked and we might want to reduce the number of people it needs to close, but I'm not comfortable leaving that judgement up to the asker entirely.

Comment: Ha... well, then why are we able to delete our question before the answer gets an upvote ? One little upvote. And maybe somebody upvoted because the answer looks great. And that's all, that upvoting person didn't even read the question, he just looked at the answer and : "Ho yeah that seems to be a good answer" ...Yes OK, but if the question was correctly understood... It would have been another kind of answer, the kinds that gently tells you to take a course

Comment: Not convinced ? I'd be glad to show you what I call a zombi question

Comment: Wait ... You can't delete your question, because it has an answer, and you probably can't delete the answer because it was accepted ... Can you remove the accepted marker, then remove the answer, then the question?

Comment: Removing the accepted mark won't allow you to delete your question. The condition for preventing deletion (if i remember) is only to have an upvoted answer. That's all it takes to disable the delete button. So of course, if you answered your own question, it works. Not if somebody else did.

Comment: There is something off in what you say... If you think this post has too much value to be deleted, why do you want to close it? Leave it open, why would you be the only one to be able to answer it? If you think it needs to be closed because it was caused by a simple typo [...] and is *unlikely to help future readers*, then just delete it.

Comment: Allowing a user to close-vote their own post could be abused (eg: get an answer (or self-answer) and then close it, robbing others from the opportunity to provide a different or better answer).

Comment: *"why are we able to delete our question before the answer gets an upvote?"* because, as has already been stated, once an answer has been posted and an upvote been given, the majority of people involved in the post have sent positive feedback regarding the question's worth. Versus the one person trying to delete the question (you), the majority wins. If you ask a question and someone answers without any votes, then it's your word vs one other person's; in those cases the system gives the asker the benefit of the doubt regarding who knows better.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel People can already unilaterally close their own questions as a duplicate, and I've never once seen or heard of anyone doing that.  So apparently it's not a form of abuse that's actually concerning in practice.  Also, in that situation they can often unilaterally *delete* the post, so why stop them from being able to close it instead?

Comment: @Servy People can't unilaterally close their own question as a duplicate, but they can **accept** a suggested duplicate. This btw happens regularly. The main difference is that accepting is more like accepting that you should have searched better and providing a signpost to a better question. It also doesn't prevent others from providing a better or different answer: that could be posted on the duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel They can flag their own post as a duplicate, and then unilaterally accept the suggested duplicate, so no, they *can* in fact unilaterally close their own post as a duplicate.  As for the rest of it, the whole point is that you're concerned with people abusively closing their questions when they don't merit closure.  *They have been able to do that for years, and simply don't* (and there are ways of addressing it were it to happen), so adding *more* ways for them to do it is not a concern.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, at least till SO can clearly explain each and every user purpose of the site, meaning of every close reason and site's content license (and somehow made sure most users took that guidance to heart).

Till that happens there need to be some level of protection against:

- [SOLVED] - close will be abused to close questions that has information for author to think they solved they problem - comments, bad guidance answer, ...
- rage quit and other reasons to vandalize their own posts
- closing good questions because "I misunderstood what I asking"

Basically original poster is not the best judge for usefulness of a question for the site and its future users.

Even for "duplicate" - I believe original author may often suggest duplicate based on what they *want question to be* and not what actually asked leading future visitors to unrelated answers. Starting with someone else's suggestion as it is done now alleviates this concern.

If you feel that your particular question must not be on the site (and you can't delete it as it has positive contributions from community) you can flag for moderator intervention and make your case for deletion. Note that you need to provide very compelling reason for deletion - content removal is not taken lightly by moderators.

Comment: Depending on the type of vandalism, it's usually caught by SmokeDetector or the vandalism bot (provided it's online). Protecting against it before it's posted is hard, but there are systems in place to try to catch it if it happens

Comment: @Zoe - I'm not involved with those so I don't know how hard it would be to add "review all closures done by OP" functionality to those bots. It probably should not be too hard...

Comment: As a way to get it closed faster, flag to close and *then* vote to close.

Comment: I'd be interested in a mod's take on the "flag then vote" alternative.  It sounds like exactly the sort of thing that mods would prefer us to *avoid* doing.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do both, @JL2210; if you have the ability to close the question (yours at...500? I think?  The rest at 3k), flagging it just uses your close vote.

Comment: Once a duplicate is proposed, the OP sees a banner that an answer might exist on the proposed duplicate-target. They have the option of accepting the duplicate, which will immediately close the question. I'm not sure what happens when they are the first to flag or vote for closure as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Whether a post should be closed is always up for debate, regardless of who composed it, and so it should always be subject to community review.

In this case, the fact that you don't think the posts are delete-worthy because the problem was "hard to track down" generates immediate suspicion that they may not also be close-worthy. (Closure is supposed to be a signpost on the way to deletion; clearly you're not planning to edit and improve the questions so why close if you're not willing to delete?)

Let the community, along with yourself via your single vote, decide whether the post has lasting value.

Answer (score 4):

Yes users should able to single-handedly close their questions.

Because right now, there are questions out there that would be closed if they had had more attention. But simply no one pay attention to these "almost, but not good enough" questions and they can't be deleted since there is (for example) an upvoted answer to the said question.

Being able to single-handedly close your own question would solve this problem.

**Edit :**

Seems like giving user such kind of power is a bit too much.

Still, what about these kind of question ? Which are not very clear, has been answered and the answer has been upvoted even though the answer's not that great, it isn't really helping much. All in all it's headache and effort for absolutely nothing. No one is going to make sens out of it, it is useless. It's not even going to show up in a google search.

What about these questions ? Let them here I guess. Or ask on meta every time it happens ?

We need a tool that can bring attention of 5 persons to a BAD question.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe allow deletion on question that has an answer that has less than 3 upvotes.

Comment: `Being able to single-handedly close your own question would solve this problem.` - no, it would solve *a part of the problem*. The problem is far too big for that alone to solve the entire problem, because there are still users who insist that their questions are fine, even when they're not.

Comment: *they can't be deleted since there is (for example) an upvoted answer to the said question.* as far as the system can tell this answer is actually something we want to preserve. Yes, good answers sometimes arise from bad questions, and that's  exactly where blocking the Original Poster of the bad question to single-handedly close their post is useful.

Comment: Not only is this only part of the problem, it is *the wrong problem*.  If the question is a sufficiently poor, inappropriate, or useless one, then the objective should be to *delete* it.  Closing it would be sufficient if it hadn't any upvoted answers, because then it would eventually be roomba'd, but in that case the OP could delete it directly.

Comment: @Zoe I must admit my approach is... A bit extreme. All I really want, is something to bring attention to a my bad question (without putting bounty, and without mentioning it here) hopping that 4 other persons would close vote my own question. Yeah the answer has been upvoted but... it ain't such a great answer, it's just weird it got upvoted

Comment: _"We need a tool that can bring attention of 5 persons to a BAD question."_ we have, that is the purpose of the review queues.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Still an issue, some of the bad questions somehow get's trough then review without being closed

Comment: @AntoinePelletier The world isn't perfect, and the queue is too big because not enough people review.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel World isn't perfect, neither is SO, neither are users. That's why I wanted to allow users to at least close their own fail and let a moderator judge if it deserve removal. But check how unpopular is my answer. Clearly no one cares about that. And I will no longer care. I will never care again. Not on SO

Answer (score 2):

I always understood that once submitted it's not YOUR post. You're the author but you [licensed the content to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). From that license "The licensor cannot revoke these freedoms as long as you follow the license terms."

The 5-vote requirement also prevents useful content from being removed for the wrong reasons, and guards against your content being maliciously removed by anyone who for any period of time has access to your account.

Comment: Still you can delete it single-handedly...

Comment: It is licensed under an open license but it is still **your** post. Licensing does not mean you relinquish ownership. You do not licence it "to SO", but simply publish it under "CC BY-SA 3.0", which applies to SO or anyone else who wants to use the content.

Comment: Taking this answer to its logical conclusion, /any/ investment of time (comment, upvote, edit) by someone who is not the asker should result in inability of the asker to delete, surely? I still agree with the answer, though - once you have posted a question you should no longer see yourself as owning the content. If people could not delete their rubbish questions, it might help them try harder next time.

Comment: But the content isn't being removed - the question is just being closed?

Comment: @Kaiido If you don't think your question should be on the site, why would you want to close it rather than delete it?

Comment: @MandyShaw But you *do* still own the content.  As Yivi says.  Posting content here does not remove ownership, it just gives others a license to copy it (with certain restrictions, such as attribution).

Comment: @JohnMontgomery what made you write this comment? Mine was pointing out that if the reason for not being able to close a question was an ownership thing, surely we would  be even less able to delete it.

Comment: @Kaiido - You can only delete it if it has at most one answer and that answer doesn't have a positive score.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ... and...? What do you guys are reading in my comment that I can't read myself? Question is "Why can't asker close it's own question?" This answer says "Because the question belongs to us". My comment says "How come we let them delete it then?".

Comment: @Kaiido - I'm reading the absence of the pretty important qualification. As apparently are others. To me, it makes perfect sense that someone can delete a question before the community engages with it in a significant positive way, and not afterward.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry can't read you here... I'm not a native speaker as you might already have noticed. But where the heck did you got this story from? What are we talking about here? The question? I made my point about it, this question seems coming from an non issue to me. The answer? I also made my point, logics tend to disprove it. Then what?

Comment: @Kaiido - I don't think it's worth your time or mine to discuss it further.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so what? You wake me up in the middle of the night and now you tell it's not worth it?

Comment: @Kaiido - No, I didn't wake you up in the middle of the night. If you have your phone set up to make some noise and wake you up when you get a ping on SO, that's your decision. I'm finding your attitude here inappropriate, and choose not to engage with it further.