# Should one downvote a question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reputation, downvotes, downvote-reason

I had asked a question which was promptly marked as duplicate as it had been asked and answered earlier. I thanked the one who directed me to the answer because I had genuinely asked this question. Then some guy downvoted my question.

Isn't marking a question as duplicate enough? If no one is contributing to it, isn't it fair to leave it alone?

Comment: You are expected to look for duplicates. One of the reasons listed on the downvote tooltip is "this question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @RobertLongson That isn't always the case. I didn't get any search results in StackOverflow. All I got were solutions in Python or Javascript (even after searching with the java tag). Why should I pay for the shortcommings of the site? Apart from that, why make it available for people to downvote once it has been marked as duplicate?

Comment: Stack Overflow's search isn't the only tool you're expected to use. Searching Google for your exact title gives me the post yours is a duplicate of as the first result.

Comment: @MikeM. Accepted. But, why make it available for people to downvote once it has been marked as duplicate?

Comment: @amuse Isn't being marked as duplicate enough? Why should it even get upvotes? No point in doing whatever amount of research if someone has already did it earlier. Isn't it?

Comment: If there's a good answer to a question with an obscure title and you create a question with a title that's far more likely to be found by searching don't you think you deserve upvotes? If however the original question has a title that's easy to find then you should have found it and you get downvotes.

Comment: In my mind, a duplicate can be good if the duplicate relation is not trivial and show research effort, and they can help extending search keywords, but if the duplicate is trivial or it can be searched easily, it is not a good duplicate and I think it is reasonable do downvote in order to discourage such action.

Comment: A poor question is a poor question. Being closed doesn't negate that fact. Sorry to be blunt, but if you don't like being downvoted, put more than a few minutes' effort into your research next time. As has been said countless times, posting a question on Stack Overflow should be a last resort, when you absolutely can't find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: @RobertLongson No I don't. I'm much more comfortable with not being praised than I'm with being reprimanded without any explanation.

Comment: A personal reminder for you: while I oppose to do so, mentioning about unpleasant or anger to downvotes may attract more downvotes to the actual questions if you stick the actual question here

Comment: If you've done something wrong and we don't tell you, how are you going to know to stop doing it?

Comment: @MikeM. A poor question is a poor question. I agree. But making someone realize it and still keeping on punishing him isn't fair. You rather do away with the concept of marking questions as duplicate.

Comment: People whose questions were quickly marked as a duplicate would have an advantage over those whose questions took longer to be marked as a duplicate, that seems even more "unfair"

Comment: @amuse If that is so, then I'm in the wrong community. I always upvote all answers that help me and seldom downvote (retract if the answer or question is later edited). I don't want to discourage people. I'm not trying to take the higher moral ground but it makes me sad.

Comment: @RobertLongson What kind of advantage?

Comment: There would be less time in which they could collect votes.

Comment: @amuse On another thought, a duplicate question which is "Non Trivial" isn't a duplicate at all and shouldn't be marked as such.

Comment: @RobertLongson Not an advantage if those are upvotes. As indicated by amuse one can mark non-trivial questions as duplicate.

Comment: If you don't downvote incorrect answers you're wasting the time of everybody else who has to try them and find they don't work. You need to think of all of the rest us and not just the one person who answered or asked a question. The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few ;-)

Comment: It's quite simple really.  Some posters do not bother to search for dups, either directly on SO or Google, because it takes a little effort and time.  Why bother doing that if you can just post it and let the SO drones look up the duplicate for you?  If Googling the exact title gives ' 'About 202,000,000 results', then, for sure, the OP is going to get a downvote from me.

Comment: Anyway, many of the dups are repwhore groundbait or voting-ring round-robins, ie.questions that the OP knew were dups when posting them.  It brings in extra rep while wasting the time of genuine contributors but, obviously, that does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys...

Comment: see also: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Comment: "I don't downvote, I don't put people down"... but making sure the bad answers are SHWON as bad isn't important in your mind? You want to make sure the poster of a bad answer doesn't feel bad, but you have no consideration towards the effect this may have on the quality of the site, and on future visitors.... which is 100% of the goal of Stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say don't down-vote a question which is a duplicate unless the question was very obvious.

This is very debatable but what I am saying is: if a user posts a question without research or at least a google then it deserves down-votes.

But if a question was asked and it has a duplicate which is not exactly the same question but something similar (which may contain the answer), then it shouldn't be down-voted or up-voted, as the user may have done his research but not found it or just wanted a better answer.

Comment: If you've done your research, say so in the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, if not they deserve down-votes.

Answer (score 8):

> I felt bad and angry.

You are taking downvotes too personally. A downvote means, and I quote:

**"This question does not show any research effort. It is unclear or not useful"**

And nothing more then that. It's not an attack on you as a user, and it's not a personal insult. It's our form of quality control here.

> Isn't marking a question as duplicate enough? Why must I keep losing
>   reps? If no one is contributing to it, isn't it fair to leave it
>   alone?

No. By asking this question, you are submitting it for public scrutiny. The first part says something about lacking research effort, and if a question is an obvious duplicate (like yours) then the fact that you asked it instead of finding and reading the dupe before shows that lack of research effort. A question being an obvious dupe is a valid reason to downvote it.

> I like StackOverflow and want to be more than just a leech.

That's great! But before you contribute here, please take your time to properly review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page carefully. Also helpful for this can be the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort. It is unclear or not useful" as a directive is vague, subjective at best. This topic will always be up for debate. Although, SO proves to be a good platform to find solutions to technical issues, it isn't a community at all.

Comment: You are right though. I shouldn't have taken it personally.

Comment: This anwser is usefull and was written in a clear (and i guesss ironic) duplicate. However OP got several downvotes