# Should I ask off-topic questioners to delete their own questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

Closing a `[off-topic | unclear | broad | opinion-based]` question takes a long time.

So lately, in addition to close-voting, I've asked the questioner to delete their own questions with an instructional (?) comment like this:

> The code you offer does not attempt to do what you desire so your
>   question is a design issue rather than a coding issue. Stackoverflow
>   deals with specific coding issues rather than design phase issues so
>   your design question is not appropriate for Stackoverflow. Please
>   delete your (off-topic) design question, but please do come back for
>   help if/when you have a question about your existing code. :-)

I change this text to fit the closing reason.

So far, I'm finding about 1 of 4 questioners are deleting their questions.

My question is:

*Is it good to explicitly ask off-topic questioners to remove their own question?*

Comment: Well, if these are blatantly off-topic, why not? Leave an explaining link to the help center if so. I'm often trigger happy, and don't waste my time leaving such comment (unless I'm out of close/delete votes).

Comment: It'll depend on whether or not the question is salvageable (both in theory and in practice).  If it's not, sure, advise them to delete it.  If it is, give them an opportunity to fix it.

Comment: I somewhat agree with Servy but I would be careful since it could contribute to a question timeout. It's probably best to CV, DV, and let nature take its course.

Comment: If it's not salvageable, yes. If an edit can fix, no.

Comment: @codeMagic If it's a bad question then them deleting it *before* it gets a closed and downvoted would *improve* their standing, from the perspective of the post-ban algorithm.

Comment: @Servy that's a good point. I guess I wasn't thinking it through enough

Answer (score 6):

I'm *really* not a happy camper about these passive-aggressive messages since it carries a huge implication that the OP is very *clearly* in the wrong for posting this question.

Closure exists to ensure that the OP has a *chance* to edit their question into shape, and if they don't, [the system generally takes care of it for us after some time anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/175248).

I don't see the value in the message.  It serves more as noise than anything constructive.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So for you, giving the OP time to improve their question is important. I agree and I often comment to the OP why their question needs improving even before close-voting. The questions I ask the OP to remove are usually "give me the code",etc. questions that seem unsalvageable.

Comment: @markE:  In that case, I'm not sure why you'd bother commenting at all, since there's little chance that your comment will guide the OP into correcting their question.

Comment: Possibly salvageable questions get "Please include a code snippet..." type comments and no immediate close-vote. Give-me-the-code questions get "Please close your question..." type comments and an immediate close vote.

Comment: @markE:  "Give me the code" questions aren't the sort of question you should be commenting on anyway; there's no reason to ask the OP to close the question; given enough time, the community will do that for them.

Answer (score 3):

The problem about asking new users to delete their questions is that it's a one way ticket to being question banned. While there are some users that deserve that, the users that are self-deleting seem different.

They *clearly* want to become good members of the community, otherwise they wouldn't be doing what you asked. **These types of messages harm the chances for new users to create good questions.**

Instead, you should be explaining how closure works, and what they should do to fix their questions during that period, assuming the question CAN be fixed. (If the question can never be fixed, it might be better deleted.)

> But the system doesn't care whether the posts are deleted or not; if you asked a dozen questions and they were all badly-received, you're probably question banned - the only difference deletion makes is that you can't fix a deleted question.
>
> - From Shog9's answer to [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810)

Comment: ban is unlikely, see: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Comment: @gnat These questions are closed, and likely down voted. Deleting them will only further the penalty. It supports my point and I added an excerpt.

Comment: @Laurel:  The only thing deleting adds to that mix is that it makes it harder to discover those questions, which restricts or prohibits the ability to improve them.  Deleting them outright doesn't net result in anything so long as there aren't any answers attached to them.

Comment: If users are repeatedly asking very low quality questions we *want* them to be question banned.  It doesn't seem clear that people asking these types of questions want to be good community members at all; the question is describing help vampires, which is very far from a good community member.  Deleting questions also wouldn't make them count for more as far as the post ban algorithm is concerned, it just doesn't make it not count like so many people think it does.

Comment: @Laurel The premise of the question is that he's posting this comment on questions that *aren't* closed yet, specifically to avoid having to have 5 people use up their close votes closing it.

Comment: @Makoto I've made it clearer that it doesn't affect the speed.

Comment: @Servy The question doesn't link anything, so it would seem that you are imagining a different type of person than I was thinking of. As a newer user, I understand how hard it is to ask good questions, and I saw the actions as something I might do if I had a bad question. And I'm certainly not a help vamp, because I have too many answers.

Comment: @Laurel So because you're not a help vampire nobody else who ever asks bad questions is a help vampire?  Sorry, but that doesn't follow.

Comment: @Servy I'm saying my interpretation is different. Are you saying that everyone who asks bad questions IS a help vampire?

Comment: @Laurel No.  You claimed that none of them were, and I'm saying that that statement is false.  I'm not asserting the converse.  I will say that many of them will be, certainly a significant portion of them.

Comment: @Servy Where did I say that? You were the one who brought up help vamps in the first place. I only said that I am not a help vamp.

Comment: You stated that all people asking questions that are close-worthy are clearly trying to be good members of the community

Comment: Oh, and you really shouldn't open your question by saying that them deleting their question will result in them being question banned, only to later quote Shog stating the opposite.  Since you now know full well that you were wrong, you should actually remove the incorrect statement.

Comment: @Servy Please try to understand what I am saying. There is no reason for a user to delete their question when asked unless they want to cooperate with the community. And I see no misinformation in my post with what I said and quoted.

Comment: And yet many of the most disruptive and abusive users are constantly deleting their questions, so clearly that's a false assumption on your part.  You'll virtually never see a question banned user not deleting their questions given that they assume it'll stop them from counting against them.  The people actually trying to become valuable members of the community are the ones who typically *don't* delete their questions right away; they try to fix them, or at least understand what they're doing wrong first.  The ones that just try to sweep it under the rug are the ones that don't care.

Comment: @Laurel So you're still going to assert that deleting the question is going to cause them to be question banned, despite knowing full well that deleting the question isn't going to contribute to them getting question banned?

Comment: @Servy Correct me if I'm wrong: having poorly received deleted posts are difficult to fix. Fixing questions is the easiest way out of a question ban. It's not fair to new users who DO want to contribute to recommend that they delete their questions instead of trying to fix them, especially when they are unaware of the consequences of deleting their questions.

Comment: @Laurel. Thanks for your feedback. Do I understand from your answer that you recommend comments to rehabilitate "give me the code" (and similar type) questions, but not the "please delete" comment I'm giving? What comment text would you suggest?

Comment: @markE Yes, you could just suggest that they add whatever is needed, and explain why. Sometimes people just don't know what to include.

Comment: @Laurel That doesn't make the user any more likely to get a quesiton ban.  It means that if they do manage to get question banned (something *very* few users manage to do) they'll have a harder time getting out of it (something very few of those that *do* get question banned even *attempt* to do).  That's *radically* different from saying deleted question will result in you *getting* question banned. That's also assuming the user is capable of improving the question, something that's possible, but *extremely* uncommon. *Very* few bad questions ever get improved enough to become good questions.

Comment: @Servy That's why I said "one way ticket". Meaning hard to get out of. In any case, there is no direction for the user to go besides to continue deleting questions that are poorly received when that's the only feedback given.

Comment: Of course there is.  They can not continue posting more bad questions.  You're making the assumption that every single question the user has ever posted, and will ever post will be bad, resulting in them getting question banned, while also assuming that they could fix the question if they actually tried. There are virtually zero such users.  People capable of fixing a question like that into a good question aren't going to ask enough bad questions to get question banned; the people who will ask enough bad questions to get question banned couldn't fix them if they did try (which they wouldn't).

Comment: @Servy Sometimes people need direction to know where exactly their question went wrong. It's incredibly frustrating to be shut down and have no clue why.

Comment: @Laurel Sounds like you didn't even read the example comment in the question then, given that it goes into quite a lot of detail about what the problems with the post are.  It's not like he's suggesting a mod insta-delete the post without comment.  You're arguing against an action that's not being proposed.