# Am I being penalized for deleting 0 score non-accepted answers?

Tags: discussion

Every so often I run through my less-than-great answers and delete those that have not been up-voted or accepted. I started a large purge about a week ago. Everything's been going as expected; I've received no deletion warnings or any indicator deleting the posts is problematic.

This morning when I came to the site I noticed 9 points were removed (5606 -> 5597). I didn't spend much time worrying about it and went to purging again. Then, after deleting a couple more, 8 more points were removed (5597 -> 5589).

This time I looked into my [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361787/chieftwopencils?tab=reputation) and saw no notifications of any negative rep changes. Why am I losing reputation without notifications?

Comment: Maybe you had an upvoted and downvoted answer so it looked like it was at 0 when it was not.  If I recall correctly the rep change shows up on the day the post was voted on not the day it was deleted.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I believe you're right. I found a -10 deep in my post list that says "There were no net reputation changes on this day".

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yep.  That would be it.

Comment: Side note: massive deletion of own posts is frowned upon... If you really want to do that I'd recommend limiting such cleanup to only awful/completely unfelpful/duplicate answers. Lack of votes does not mean useless answer - could be just less traveled one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I haven't read that about answers. I know deletion of questions if frowned upon and can, in some cases, lead to a ban. Most of the answers I'm deleting are older and noobish or were unfortunate contributions to poor questions.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils your wrong on both cases.  Deleting questions will not cause a question ban.  A history of asking poorly received questions will cause a ban (whether they are deleted or not), and leaving poorly received answers will also lead to a bad.  But in general, mass deleting content can be seen as someone potentially rage quitting, and might draw the attention of a moderator to look into it.  I also don't see the value in deleting posts just because they have no score.  I have found plenty of answers to my problems in unvoted answers.

Comment: @psubsee2003, I'd need a link to confirm that. While looking into this issue I found that question deletions do count towards a ban. I also have not seen where "mass deleting content" would be seen as potential rage-quitting; what I read is that it's taken that you must be contributing large amounts of posts and "apparently they are not suitable for the site". The way I currently, and plan to continue to, handle deletions is hope for a warning if anything I'm doing is wrong. Haven't had one so I assume everything is fine.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils [psubsee2003 is right about deleting questions.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban/311812#311812)

Comment: @Kendra, well, on that note, [I have a feeling there's a lot of editing to be done](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). My comment says "in some cases" while psubsee says they do not with absolute certainty.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils if I understand your comment, you are misreading what it says.  Deleted posts do count, they just do not count differently.  You don't get penalized for deleting a post (in most cases, there are exceptions as Shog pointed out in Kendra's link), but deleting a post does not magically erase the negative impact to your question/answer history.

Comment: Usually deleting answers just because they're scored 0 is wrong. If you put the effort in to writing a good answer they probably are useful to future readers, even if those readers don't/can't vote. Sometimes you'll get an accept 2 years after you answered. Or a random burst of votes. You took the time to write it, don't make that wasted effort without a good reason.

Comment: @Flexo, Perhaps I wasn't clear; I don't delete them just because they're scored 0. They're the only ones I can without warnings. I'd delete a particular answer that is both up-voted and accepted; rep isn't as important to me as the quality of my content. I've been programming for a few months longer than my account life and over that time I've grown in my ability to contribute and asses quality content. I think keeping my account consistent with my own expectations is reason enough to delete them. The goal being to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: be careful about massive deletion of your own answers: if you reach the limit, post a bad/unfixable answer and get a lot of downvotes, you won't be able to delete it until the next day. Keep some power under the foot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you remove answers with a score of 0 you might have missed that the post had an equal number of upvotes and an equal number of downvotes.

If you remove that post your reputation is re-calculated as if those upvotes and downvotes never occurred.

You can use this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/479028) if you quickly want to see the votes on your answers.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Given your rep, you can just click the score, too. You have to be on the page with the post, however.

Comment: @Laurel, yes, I know. That's why I immediately felt silly after rene commented that on my question. I just wasn't using my head. I do always go to the post and re-read it; I have to be there to delete it anyway. Thanks.