# My account is blocked, yet the badge tracker says I have a positive record

Tags: discussion, post-ban

To start off, I'm not here saying I can't ask questions, my account is blocked, boohoo, etc., etc. I accept I'm blocked for some reason.

As indicated above, my account is blocked from asking questions. I was looking through the badges in the "Badge Tracker", and I noticed that on the Curious Badge, I have a positive question record.

**How can I have a positive question record if I'm blocked?**

Surely there must be some kind of error with the positive question record? Or am I missing something?

---

Update: So wow! I can ask questions again! It's not what I came looking for, but that doesn't mean I don't appreciate it :) Thanks guys! (And gals.)

I guess I was kind of close to the ban limit :)

Comment: You do seem to have a lot of questions with a score of 0 which is not seen as positive by the system, but not sure how that factors into the badge in question.

Comment: If your account is blocked, you must have a bunch of deleted stinkers.  A short survey of your questions doesn't suggest to me you're the kind of user the block was created for.

Comment: @Will I have 2 deleted with -2, and one with -1 - as Brad Larson detailed in the comment on the answer

Comment: That doesn't seem bad at all.  Almost makes me want to serially upvote ya.

Comment: @Will thanks! But that's not why I asked the question - I'm not looking for that! I get that due to my lack of knowledge the question I probably would ask have already been asked in a similar way.

Comment: Congrats on getting unblocked, and all the apparent rep you got. (Meta Effect worked wonders for you, intended or not!) Just keep asking good, well-formed, on-topic questions and you should be heading away from the ban fast. Good luck!

Comment: *"How can I have a positive question record if I'm blocked?"* - shouldn't that be *"How am I blocked if have a positive question record ?"*. your problem  seems to be that you have a positive question record and a badge for that  than the fact that you're blocked ._.

Comment: @TJ My concern was that maybe there was a bug with the positive question record, as by my thinking, as I was blocked, then I shouldn't have a positive question record.

Comment: Btw @CalvT븃 , the symbols in your name mean "Byut", and it's not exactly a real word. `What does the symbol in my name mean? Apparently it translates to Byus. Here are some more: 뭇믓븃숖숃숁` none of these are. hahaha

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5` is the formula for "positive record" for that badge. Thanks to Brad Larson's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323364/account-is-blocked-yet-badge-tracker-says-i-have-a-positive-record/323366#comment345855_323366), we can figure out your exact formula for the badge. You have 3 deleted questions. All three of these are downvoted, bringing you to 4 downvoted questions. You also have 6 closed questions. So your score would be `(30-4-6-3)/30 = .56`, putting you just over the threshold for the badge.

Most of your questions are zero score. While these don't count against you for the badge, they *do* weigh slightly against you for the ban. (How much is unknown as the SE team does not disclose *that* algorithm.) So I would guess your zero scored questions are weighing you down for the ban, along with your couple of deleted and downvoted questions, but you have a "positive record" by not having an overly negative record. I would hazard a guess that you're right on the edge of the ban and one or two upvotes would get you out. I would also guess that if one of your zero score questions got an upvote, you'd get the badge.

---

Badge formula was obtained from the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#67399) on MSE.

Comment: There are three deleted questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27387134/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/27148024/19679 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/24834914/19679 , all downvoted, which is probably enough to just cross the ban threshold.

Comment: Shog has said that system deleted questions count a little more the self deleted questions as well.  Might just be one more straw that broke the camels back.

Answer (score -7):

Following up with what everyone else has said, deleting your own questions is very, very highly frowned upon here. If people are downvoting your question, it is better to attempt to fix it according to whatever feedback you're getting in the comments and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines rather than deleting it.

tl;dr **Deleting should be an absolute last resort,** and should not be used to remove negative rep from a poorly received question.

Comment: official stance seems to be that deleting questions that are 0 score, not answered and without close votes is harmless: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)