# Does a zero-vote question affect rate limit/question bans?

Tags: discussion, voting, post-ban, zero-voted-posts

I know this is a close duplicate of some other questions but none appears to ask exactly this question.

Does a zero-vote question affect ability to post in future?

I am having trouble getting my reputation off the ropes. It is weighed down by a few very old, admittedly poor, questions.  Recently I have been putting a lot of work into my questions because I value the service I get here on SO.  But I am beginning to think it is a hopeless task, because I do believe the fact that the ability-to-post algorithm has absolutely no timeout is a mistake.

If you have time, please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859059/in-xamarin-xaml-how-do-i-set-a-constraint-on-a-relativelayout-using-a-style). I put a lot of effort into this question. I gave a good title, phrased as a specific answerable question. I gave code examples. I linked to a fully buildable solution on an external server. And I used English to the best of my ability. Nevertheless, I have not had one positive vote.

Can someone please tell me anything I can do to free myself of a reputation gained when I was not even aware that SO was tightening up its posting guidelines?

Comment: for newer accounts there is a time out - [rolling rate limits are explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/165773). I heard that this sometimes doesn't work for older accounts like your - in this case it is worth considering an option to delete account and restart at 1 question a week [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234518/165773)

Comment: But you got an answer didn't you? You even accepted it. Upvotes on the question are just a bonus.

Comment: "Does a zero-vote question affect reputation" well, it doesn't increase your reputation.  But, on the bright side, it doesn't decrease it, either.

Comment: Either way you triggered the Meta Effect, so you got your upvotes eventually. :P

Comment: I do not think that missing upvotes will limit you. There is even a badge Tumbleweed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban)

Comment: He is asking about zero vote question, not self-censoring. Even if the actual cause could be based on the suggested duplicate, it has not been established.

Answer (score 26):

The *average* score of your questions is considered when we determine if someone should probably slow down with their questions and spend some more time looking at how to ask good questions.

If you have 5 questions, 4 of them zero scored, one of them negatively scored, well - that's not a great average score.

However, *most* people start off with a couple of zero scored questions, then one or two that get an upvote, and then they're basically out of the reach of any automatic or dynamic rate limits.

Note, the system also counts the number of times you've edited your questions too - so putting a little more work into them helps not only to possibly get an upvote, but also to tell the system that you care about your questions (which is all it's trying to determine). If people are understanding your questions and answering them, you're *probably* doing alright.

In short, if you're putting thought into your questions, you *probably* don't have anything to worry about. If you can't seem to catch an upvote on any of them, check your tags - are you sure you've got all applicable (major) tags on them that should be there? It could just be a question of visibility.

Comment: The last paragraph is why people add filler tags that are otherwise completely irrelevant to their question.

Answer (score -10):

> I am having trouble getting my reputation off the ropes

Try answering questions in your expertise areas. Upvotes on answers bring twice as more rep than upvotes on questions.

Comment: However, said answers don't count *nearly* as much towards rate limt/question bans, which is what he is asking about (despite misusing the term "reputation")

Comment: @BradleyDotNET is right, although they *do* count some. (I'm not sure whether good questions also count toward avoiding answer bans, but the point never seems to come up.)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about if zero-score questions count towards the question ban, not about how to earn reputation.