# Chain-deleting questions [10k users]

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I just found two extremely similar questions posted within about 5 minutes apart from each other:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517849/node-js-support-for-function-prototype-name
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517914/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-that-a-function-expression-is-assigned-to-in-java

I can't remember the user who posted the first one since I wasn't paying attention, but the second asker was randombits with 6473 reputation. This seems like unusual behavior to me for such a high-rep user, and I wanted to ask if this was something that we condone.

Comment: Same user. Seems to be a particularly bad habit of theirs. **Almost 30%** of their questions are deleted.

Comment: @BoltClock how can you check that? Is that something anyone can check?

Comment: As stated in your title, you need 10k rep in order to see deleted posts. I can tell how many questions a user has in total because diamond moderators can see all of a user's deleted posts from their profile.

Comment: @BoltClock makes sense. I thought there might be a SQL query available or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as a user is not trying to delete questions that other users have put valuable time and effort into answering, if a user wants to hastily delete their question because it turned out to be something simple and someone pointed it out in a quick comment (and not in a full-blown answer), let them. Most of these questions are unlikely to be useful to future readers anyway.

A user with a significant portion of deleted questions on their account simply needs to learn to think twice and do their research before posting. Furthermore, having a large number of deleted questions contributes greatly to a question ban.

Comment: ["Deleted posts are mostly irrelevant to the question ban. If someone tells you otherwise, tell them they're wrong; if you see a meta post that says otherwise, edit it..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Comment: @gnat: Sooo... are you going to edit it or not?

Comment: of course not - everything Shog says to do, I do the opposite :)