# I realized my question is dumb. Delete it, right?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I asked a dumb question.

In a comment someone pointed it out and I immediately realized my error.

Someone had posted a one line code answer but it didn't really answer the question.

I deleted it but I realized that I have now deleted the work of people who commented.

Should I have deleted it? There is a very small possibility that it would have helped someone else.

Comment: If it was unlikely to help others, then you did right in deleting it. Was it a typo pointed out to you that made you realize your error, or some other small error of a similar nature? If it was, those even have their own close reason. The only "effort" really wasted was the answerer's, but if the answer was wrong or didn't answer the question, you probably didn't waste much there.

Comment: *the work of people who commented* A comment is not "work". It's just a comment.

Comment: It was a just obvious conceptual misunderstanding

Comment: It counts towards the automatic post ban.  Deleting the work of someone who spent time trying to help you (the lone answerer) is considered heavily in the algorithm.  Keep the link around in case you want to undelete the question in future.

Comment: @Will - Yes, but, if the community deletes the question as opposed to the OP it weighs even more.

Comment: @TravisJ hmmm, that's not how I read Shog9's answer on the question I'm alluding to [insert link here that I can't find].  I believe self-delete of answered questions counts more because of the assholish behavior of homework vampires who delete their answered questions so they won't get caught cheating.  That's way worse than just asking a bad question.

Comment: @Will - This was the post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/1026459 . It basically says that only if you delete it *directly after an answer is posted* that it thinks you were being hostile, otherwise it states in nice bold text that **Deleted posts are mostly irrelevant to the question ban** and attempts to hammer the point that "What matters are *poorly-received posts*. That is, questions that are downvoted, closed, or flagged as inappropriate in some way."

Comment: @Will Also, shog's post doesn't say that deleting a question with an answer is way worse than having a question so bad that the community feels it needs to be deleted, he says it's way worse than you having done nothing (thereby leaving a post with no votes there).  He never compares it to any posted deleted for another reason, or a post with any indications of negative feedback (closure, downvotes, etc.)

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, inquisitiveIdiot, we're all idiots here. Present company excluded, of course:P

Comment: I've put a lot of work into some comments, particularly those that have involved secondary discussions arising out of answers, such as those around usability or device compatibility

Comment: @TravisJ that wasn't the post I was thinking about.  If I come across that I'll update.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, it is best to just delete these yourself.

Glorfindel outlines what may happen, and removing it before that scenario plays out is desirable.

If the community answers your question, and then 5 users have to close it, and then another 3 have to delete it, all of that weighs very heavily against you with regards to the recividism system. Repeating such a process will cause the automated question ban system to begin to kick in.

I think it is pertinent to keep in mind that asking a question at Stack Overflow should literally be your last resort. The last thing you want to do is add a question on to the umpteen millions of other questions. Retrace your steps, consult the official documentation, use breakpoints, recreate the error environment, look for similar problems, but by all means, don't pile another question on if it will not stand the test of time.

Comment: _asking a question at Stack Overflow should literally be your last resort_ Well said

Comment: Um, good answer, but "literally your last resort" is putting it too strongly. If you're thinking of killing yourself over fixing that maddening error message, maybe ask a question on Stack Overflow first. :P

Comment: I've personally found myself asking some "dumb" questions as well, questions that another user may have found easy. But i have never created a duplicate. This website is mainly used to share knowledge, and as such it should be used. Duplicate questions are a problem, of course, but if you cannot find it after looking for it, probably posting a question is the best thing you can do. Expecially for less used languages or frameworks.

Comment: TravisJ's statement highlighted in @jonatan's comment above should be incorporated onto the banner page on StackOverflow. It crystallizes how people should be using the place. I don't think anyone has ever articulated it better.

Answer (score 19):

Questions like these are often closed with the following reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Then, usually, [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) kicks in after a few days:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as RemoveAbandonedClosed.

Deleting it now just speeds up the process, so it's fine.

Comment: I never realized it was called Roomba before... could Stack Exchange get into some sort of legal trouble with iRobot over that name choice? The user name is "Community" but the help page's url is "roomba"...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: More likely they appreciate the free advertising. But the only "legal trouble" would be a Cease & Desist which SE would then honor...

Comment: does it count toward question ban? if the question has no answer?

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent I don't know. Details of that algorithm are kept secret. But one or two deleted questions don't cause a ban, you definitely need more of them. And good questions (of which the OP has quite a few) provide compensation for bad/deleted questions.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent (cc Glorfindel) see the meta post linked in the [comment by Travis J](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337433/i-realized-my-question-is-dumb-delete-it-right?cb=1#comment410487_337433). Unanswered questions can probably be deleted, what matters for the ban is the negative score. Deletion only changes visibility of the negative-scored question (for better of for worse). As I understand that intentionally vague post, deletion mostly plays a part if your question has answers (and that also makes a lot of sense to me).