# Will I get penalized for deleting a wrong answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, post-ban

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478658/efficient-way-to-compare-associative-array-values-without-using-foreach) and found an answer to it eventually. Or so I thought.

It turns out that my answer was in fact wrong. My immediate response was to delete/remove the answer. However, by that time the answer received a negative down vote.

I vaguely remember reading somewhere that deleting down-voted answers is not a good idea and repeating the act will attract a penalty.

I have deleted a couple of such answers previously and so am wary of doing it again. However, I feel I should do it anyway for the simple reason that the solution given by me is wrong.

Thoughts?

Comment: deleting negatively scored posts only affects users with very low rep and no other useful contributions. I think with over 5K you're out of that danger zone ...

Comment: @rene Does that mean even if I start purging all my down-voted answers, I will most likely be in the green zone? (Not that I intend to do)

Comment: I only know one case where a mod flag was raised for a user that deleted their answers day after day but that included accepted, upvoted answers. If you delete 6 down voted answers per day (it is capped at that) you should be fine

Comment: I am not exactly sure that it's deleting downvoted answer as much as posting badly received answers repeateadly @rene.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, there's no penalty. In fact, deleting wrong or not-useful answers is a *good thing* that we want to encourage. A [peer-pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure)  badge is even awarded for users who delete an answer with a score of −3 or lower. (But don't feel like you need to wait that long if you figure out for yourself that the answer is wrong!)

The concern about deleted answers counting against you only applies to users without other useful contributions. If you aren't posting any answers that get upvotes, and you're deleting a bunch of downvoted answers, then you are in the danger zone. You are far from the danger zone.

Furthermore, [the dangers of deleted posts are often overstated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/366904).

*That said*, I don't advocate deleting answers just because they have received a downvote. People downvote for all sorts of reasons. You probably shouldn't delete the answer unless you now see for yourself what the problem is, *and* you have decided that you cannot fix the problem by editing (or don't need to, because someone else already posted a better answer).

Comment: Deleted answers do count against you in some ways still, don't they? For example, doesn't it figure into the formula for when the Socratic badge is awarded?

Comment: Uhh why would deleted answers figure into the calculation for a Socratic badge? That badge has to do with asking questions. @sur

Comment: Oh, right. Haha. True.