# My no score, no answer question, I can no longer verify future answers to

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question with no answers (or score), for a problem I no longer have, on a system I no longer have access to. So I can never verify the answers.

[How would I check how busy the HDD is with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703598/how-would-i-check-how-busy-the-hdd-is-with-php)

It feels like a loose end at the moment. The wisdom of meta seems to be that questions with answers have value even if I cannot choose which to accept *but* this one has no answers and is not adding much by way of value. There is also a good chance that there is not going to be an answer because of a number of technical complications (cloud specifics mostly).

What is the best approach in this case?

1. Leave it up, hope for an answer, and accept one if it looks about right.
2. Leave it and never accept any answers (not something I like).
3. Go for a delete on the grounds of "too broad".
4. Something else (that I have not yet considered)

Clarification: I'm not worried about deleting a question as in [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban) and more asking what the best way to handle this situation is. In my early days, I learned how bans work the hard way.

Comment: Just leave it up, and not accept an answer. You don't have to accept answers, you can simply leave it to community voting to surface the correct answer.

Comment: If you leave it alone [the roomba might delete it for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

Comment: I choose option 3 personally because it does feel too broad to be honest and I don't think roomba will catch it unless it's closed. The dupe probably covers it.

Comment: Though rare, there have been times when I've found an unanswered question had enough information to help me solve my own problem.

Comment: I think in this case it would be even rarer @NathanArthur. The question has had 34 views in 10 months and some of them will be due to this meta question. I'd also be wary of the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) Matthew.

Comment: I'd go with option 2

Comment: "I'm mostly in the camp that you shouldn't fear deletion, you should fear the loss of useful content." No useful content, no loss.

Comment: @Bugs Does it have more than one comment? It would otherwise be eligible for deletion according to the rules for questions a year old in a few months. (I missed that bullet point when I posted the link but I don't want to add views to the question by checking again.)

Comment: @BSMP Yeah it had two comments. Not sure how relevant they are though. Could be flagged to be removed.

Comment: Didn't we have this unaccepted answer percentage in the profile a few years ago?

Comment: @simbabque: Yes, but it was removed because users would badger askers with low accepted-answer percentages and refuse to answer their questions until they got that number up.

Comment: I love questions with unaccepted answers because it gives my answer a chance to [make it to the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top).

Comment: This is a nice way to bring attention to a question without using bounties.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you think the question (and possibly a solution) will still useful for someone else, because it's a common or interesting problem, just leave it up. Someone will eventually stumble upon it and might answer it, you can upvote without accepting a particular answer.

If the question isn't very well written, has no views, no (up)votes, no answers, no comments with useful insights, and you have no more interest in it, just delete it.