# What is supposed to happen during a 6 month asking ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Got banned after being banned for stuff such as:

- I was supposed to know that "[javascript promise chains not waiting for previous promise to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207086/javascript-promise-chains-not-waiting-for-previous-promise-to-execute)" - a question (I didn't even know existed) was a duplicate for my "[Adding a parameter to a function in .then() breaks the behaviour of a promise in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478165/adding-a-parameter-to-a-function-in-then-breaks-the-behaviour-of-a-promise-in)".
  I probably would have, If I was educated on the subject, but then, I would not have to ask.
- My [Why is Node.js installation unpacking some Python packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487917/why-is-node-js-installation-unpacking-some-python-packages) is a duplicate of [Why does node.js need python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709739/why-does-node-js-need-python). Just the title of the latter is actually an answer to my question. And no, it did not show up in the possible duplicate questions, so I did ask.

Imho, a duplicate question is actually a good way lead more people to a desired answer. People, who are looking for it using different keywords.

- I also got downvoted by people giving leaving comments such as "the questions shows lack of knowledge on the subject". Ok, Next time I'll ask when I'm educated enough to know the answer.

I do ask honest question, after I do my homework and after I check other questions. I am polite and upvote good answers. I thank all those who did not look down on my questions and took the time to answer them.

So here I am, about to create another account, so I can continue asking, since somebody thought it is a good idea to ban me for a full-frikkin-half-year. How does a 6 month ban help anyone? Why not 3? Why not 12? What is supposed to happen during that time?

Dupe edit: There are only three sentences with question marks, at the end, which, together with the title make up the question. Very clear I believe, not duplicate, asking about the 6 month period. The "duplicate" part is actually unique, related to my specific situation, explaining I was asking honest questions, got great answers, helful to me and others (or asked not-to-smart-ones and removed them). But here I am with a six month ban.

Comment: You are supposed to take some time to think on how your strategy has not been working so far, and hopefully learn to better use the site to achieve better results. For you, and for everyone else.

Comment: Hi, Im low rep like you. First you don't get ban for duplicate. You get ban for negative score question. And a duplicate is not a bad thing the community agree about this. Most of your question is about dupe.

Comment: You haven't been question banned for the questions you are linking. Those have not downvotes. You have been banned for other questions, that you must have deleted.

Comment: Unrelated thought, but I'd be interested to see how effective duplicate questions actually are as signposts with "different keywords".

Comment: _"So here I am, about to create another account, so I can continue asking"_ **Don't do this.** If the mods catch you, and with you saying here that you're planning to that's likely, your new account will likely either be merged with the old or outright deleted. You'd be making a new account to get around the automated ban system which is a huge no-go.

Comment: There is no "strategy". And for all my questions, I got very helpful answers from people, who were actually willing to help. There really is nothing I can do with people thinking my questions are dumb and downvoting. Or with not knowing a different question, that uses a very different terminology is a solution for me. No period can change this.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted some questions, after I got answers pointing out that I really have asked something not worth it.
And yes, it is my first ban.

Comment: @Marko36 "Thinking they're dumb" isn't the point of downvotes, it's a quality ranking system. Is it possible at least one downvote you've received is what you said here? Sure, anything's possible. But unless someone has explicitly told you that's why they downvoted, you really can't know for sure.

Comment: Two duplicate closed questions with a 0/0 score definitely don't cause a question ban.

Comment: _"I have deleted some questions, after I got answers pointing out"_ That counts pretty heavily against you. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/2607247) from one of the Stack Overflow Team for proof of that.

Comment: @Kendra The question you linked, which mine is supposed to be a duplicate of, does totally *not* ask about the 6 months period like mine does. This is what I am complaining about. Quick, condescending judgements.

Comment: @Marko36 That question _is 100% about the question ban._ That's what you're in right now, or very close to. If you want out of it, that question is _the only answer._ My judgement of this being a duplicate was indeed **not** condescending, it was my trying to get you the information you need as quick as possible so you can use it to help yourself.

Comment: We're not being condescending. We're just trying to give you guidance, even though you have hidden us some relevant information from the question.

Comment: Moreover: _"I also got downvoted by people giving leaving comments"_ Please don't go that route. You cannot really prove that downvotes also came from the same people commenting on your question. Making such a suggestion doesn't contribute positively to a constructive exchange.

Comment: @Marko36 There is no condescension here or judgement. Marking a question as a duplicate is not supposed to be derogatory, it helps you get the information you want faster. Answer me this, if you walked into a library looking for some information out of a book, would you rather the librarian called up an author and got them to write a new book for you that could take weeks or would you rather they pointed you in the direction of an existing book? It is the same with duplicates, all we're doing is saying that the book is already written, here it is.

Comment: If you really just want to ask how the 6 month were choosen, then I suggest you remove the whole duplicate part from the question and ask explicitly about this. I also don't think that regular users can help you with this, maybe moderators can, but I'm also not so sure about that.

Comment: @Marko36 Why is 6 months too long? You aren't stopped from looking at the site and other answered questions and this is a free service that **you are choosing to use of your own volition**. Nobody is forcing you to be here, nor are you entitled to the services here if you refuse to follow the rules.

Comment: Based on the moderator answer I recommend reading the [tour]. Maybe be their is a miss understanding between what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: The majority of your question is answered in the linked post. You go on about what you have/haven't done, as far as you see, with only a couple sentences about _why_ the 6 months. Your title doesn't even ask _why_ 6 months, it asks _what should happen_ during that 6 months. What should happen is you should be doing what the linked question says. Which means, the core/majority of your question _as practically everyone here has read it_ is answered in the linked question.

Comment: @Ethan Field I didn't know all this. Thank you. Especially for the part explaining why 6, not 5 months ban is a good idea.

Comment: @Marko36 I never mentioned why 6 months is a good ban time, nor did I bring up a 5-month ban. I asked you why you thought that 6 months was too long. You must have a reason why you think that 6 months is too long, otherwise you wouldn't have bought it up.

Comment: @Marko36 I imagine the 6 month length has been chosen more or less arbitrarily. If you want to propose that the ban length should be different you are welcome to write a feature-request detailing why would it be a good idea, what's wrong with the current implementation, and exactly what time length do you propose, and how did you arrive at the choice of such a length. You have to consider that since you are currently question banned, your question will probably be seen as biased, though.

Comment: @Ethan Field Yes. I got no answer from you, except for "you can get t f out of here if you don't like it".

Comment: @Marko36 I didn't answer your question, no. But you didn't answer mine. I'd be happy for you to stick around as a contributor to the site, at no point did I tell you to leave. You are as welcome here as I am. Now, if you'd like to tell us all why you think 6 months is too long of a period for a ban I'm sure we'd be happy to discuss this with you as calm, understanding adults.

Comment: @Ethan Field :) Anyway, gotta go now. Thanks for the intensive discussion. I will delete my now useless account prolly tomorrow.

Comment: @Marko36 I don't think your account is useless and it'd be a damn shame if you did delete it. You have questions and answers that have quite clearly helped people, hence being accepted and upvoted. It would be unfortunate to lose those and your future as a contributor over this.

Comment: @Ethan Field  Well, I it is not ok to have multiple accounts. Are you sure that deleting the account removes the questions too? I did ask some general or off-topicy questions, or some that might be seen as dupe (not by me, though), so I deleted them. 6 month jail time is way too much for me (thus this question). I want/need to start over.

Comment: Marko, deleting your account does not delete your question or answers. The content remains in the network.

Comment: @Marko36 You can get out of the ban before the 6 month point, you just have to try. It's hard work, but it is entirely possible. Also, from the linked duplicate, _"If you opt to delete your account and then later return to the site, your ability to ask questions may be limited to one question per week until you have demonstrated an ability to ask useful questions."_ So it's 100% feasible to delete and restart, but you will be rate limited.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks for the tip. However, I am not into this "hard work and hoping" to be able to use the site again. 6 months. I don't thinks my crimes, except for being off-topic sometimes, were this hard. I want SO to be a place of help, hopefully my contribution, not to present a challenge.

Comment: That is entirely understandable, and if you think 6 months is a bit long, again, post a request specifically about that. Post *honestly* how you got into this situation, and why you honestly think that the punishment is a bit harsh for the crime, and what you would suggest instead and why that's better than the status quo. If the SO developers agree, it's in their power to change it.

Comment: @Marko36 Oh, one more heads up: Since you have contributions, account deletion isn't going to be the fastest or easiest thing in the world, so... Hang tight while you wait. (Not trying to talk you out of it, just setting your expectations. If you feel it's better to restart, there's mechanisms in place.)

Comment: @Marko36 Just one comment from a guy who never saw this question til now: you say “I am not into this hard work and hope” thing; on a more general level, all I can tell you is that’s the best you can do when pursuing any objective in life. Honestly. That’s it.

Comment: @Dan Bron I like this equation: "consistent effort over time * good information * certain level of risk/creativity/originality". But in this case, fixing my 2 or 3 questions that others and I have found deletion-worthy and waiting s i x months, hoping to be able to ask questions again, is not an objective in life. Not for me at least, and I wonder how many people waited without opening another account. 6 months is ridiculous. How is that better then 4 months? Or one? (Still no answer to this question of mine. Simply marked as duplicate.)

Comment: @Marko36 I think the answer is: there is no objective, scientific way to determine such a threshold. Any such effort would be futile and useless. Some number had to be chosen, and as (a) humans are fans of simple solutions, and (b) have standardized on a year as a until of time and (c) 2 is a low, simple, and common divisor, then (qed) half a year was plucked out of thin air as a quick value to a unquantifiable problem. I can’t imagine there’s anything more to it than that. I like your formula, btw.

Comment: The ban needs to be long enough to ensure the receiver notices it, and doesn't ignore it and just wait it out. It also has to incentivize the behaviour we want here; showing effort, writing clear, concise questions, doing research, and generally not being a drain on the community.  If you could just wait out the ban, all that happens is cause more problems for the community down the road.  If you want to ask another question, it benefits you *and* the community to adhere to our guidelines and standards.

Comment: Here are your deleted questions, score < 0, which are also contributing to your question ban: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/52415055) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/52304136) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/52048148) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/52026105) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/51863859))

Answer (score 16):

Those are not the questions you were banned for. They have not been downvoted. What you *have* been banned and downvoted for are gems such as:

- Good publishing platform for an IT blog
- Wanted: Simple Node.js cloud hosting
- Do the benefits of Node being async outweigh the troubles it brings?

The first two are blatantly off-topic, the latter one is borderline technical and on-topic, but heavily discussion focused and thereby off-topic. And those weren't even beginner mistakes, you've been on the site for a while before asking those; you should know the ropes by now. Overall, you have a borderline track record with your questions, with some having been well received and some just being very hit and miss. And you just happened to dip beyond the threshold and are blocked for the time being.

Please be careful in the future not to ask blatantly off-topic questions and you should be able to stay on the right side of the threshold.

Comment: How are these off-topic? What topic? Where else should have I asked them?

Comment: Sounds like you really need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Did it. But then I came across some very general, but very helpful "off-topic" stuff such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js/

Comment: Uhm… that is *closed as off-topic by Ry-♦ Feb 19 at 12:12*.

Comment: For historical reasons such posts might be kept around, but don't use them as justification to post your own off-topic questions.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: @deceze Exactly. But look at the upvotes. My point is, that even though a bunch of elders deem a question "off-topic", it can still be very popular and helpful. Same goes for "duplicate". This question of mine is def not dupe, although marked as such - 6 month period  I am asking about remains unanswered.

Comment: Firstly, age has nothing to do with the ability to mark something as off-topic. Anyone with 15 reputation can flag a post as off topic. Secondly, the duplicate clearly explains the ban process, why it happened and the steps to take to ensure it does not happen again. You have asked multiple questions here where you should only have asked 1. If you want to know why a 6 month ban period is the standard, I would suggest you first look for an existing question and then raise another if one does not exist.

Comment: asked: 8 years, 7 months ago and viewed: 1,186,426 times  for 1266. For you it look like good question statistically it's noise.

Comment: @Marko36 Such questions exactly informed the decision to make them off-topic. That question is a heap of random links now. Not much more useful than Google really, and Google at least removes stale links.

Comment: @Marko36 According to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2353818/timeline) of that post, the last time it was voted on in either direction was back in 2013. A _lot_ has changed about what is/is not on-topic since then. Also of note... It was closed _even back then._ A moderator, really a community Team member, is the only reason it was reopened back then.

Comment: No vote on this question for years, it's just a link cimetery. No one want to maintain. Prone to become flood by spam.