# Bug while upvoting comments on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-votes

When I upvote a comment, the color of the upvote arrow changes and clicking it again will undo the upvote.

For example:

[image: Upvoted comment]

However, when I refresh the page, upvote icon becomes gray again and I can click the upvote icon again:

[image: Highlighted upvote no longer visible]

This will actually increase the upvote count of the comment even further, even though I already upvoted the comment. I first thought this was a visual glitch, but even after refreshing, the new upvote count remains.

This appears to only affect Meta. If I try it on the main site (or on teams), the icon stays colored.

Comment: Upvote me for science!

Comment: As a note, after a refresh it _shouldn't_ undo your comment upvote- You can only undo it for (I think) 60 seconds, or until you refresh the page. However, I was able to reproduce this myself.

Comment: @RageAgainstTheVirtualMachine I upvoted your comment a few times. On my screen, you have 11 upvotes right now.

Comment: Don't do it too much or you might get rate limited! :)

Comment: I've just had this happen to me as well, was able to upvote a comment on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374618/4528269) repeatedly.

Comment: Let's hope we don't get banned for voting fraud though! ^^

Comment: @g00glen00b When it's hard to see what you have/haven't voted on, not sure it can really be called "fraud" :) (I keep, even knowing this, forgetting what I've voted on already in the question and answer Ethan just linked.)

Comment: @Wurd _now_ you tell me!

Comment: @Kendra Me too, I'm just holding off on voting, for the time being, don't want to skew the comments sections.

Comment: a bunch of meta regulars might get suspended for serial upvoting of comments

Comment: I managed to upvote it even with the "too late to undo"-message.

Comment: @gnat But they are not upvoting multiple comments from the same user! Does this fall under the "serial vote" definition? :P

Comment: Since comment voting anarchy mode seems to have been unlocked, I wonder if I can upvote my own comment then...

Comment: Nope, not even if I fake a request. That's a shame

Comment: @Cerbrus server side validation is evil isn't it

Comment: @gnat: Apparently, it's pretty lenient on Meta, nowadays...

Comment: View : 67 times .. comment upvoted 300+..

Comment: Curiously enough, it doesn't happen with older upvoted comments. I've tried to re-upvote a comment I had upvoted a few months back, and it doesn't seem possible (since it's shown as upvoted, correcty, it won't let me cast another vote; and making the request directly will report that I can't vote for that comment, as should be).

Comment: No repro on Firefox 62.0 on Windows 7 but repro'd on Chrome 69.0.3497.100. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: @TylerH Repro on Firefox 62.0.2 in a Mac. Have you tried reloading the page before re-casting your vote?

Comment: Repro - was able to upvote multiple times in Chrome and observe the changes in Firefox.

Comment: @Nick, at least in FF for iPhone, I can’t reproduce in the main site. But can reproduce here.

Comment: Got "ban" for too mutch request. .. beacause i upvoted to mutch ..

Comment: @RageAgainstTheVirtualMachine Sorry, you didn't make the top voted comment in all of meta, only the [3rd highest voted comment](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/903291/highest-voted-comments). There are two comments higher than your (current) 420 votes, with 455 and 502 votes as of last week.

Comment: @DavyM **Currently at 447**. One down, two to go. :P

Comment: @Yivi 456, one to go ;D

Comment: @DavyM Sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up <3. We were in the process of doing a smoke test of Entity Framework Core. Looks like we have a few more issues to resolve. Time to write some tests!

A build of our master branch has been pushed out to meta now and all should be well with the world.

Apologies for the inconvenience. Hope you enjoyed the unbounded comment upvotes while they lasted :)

Comment: This [may be happening again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374897)...