# I can upvote infinitely on comments on meta posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, meta

After I upvote a comment and refresh the page, I am able to upvote again. I tried on other posts, too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Again?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374620/bug-while-upvoting-comments-on-meta) (Yeap, just confirmed that's broken again)

Comment: But again, this only works for newish comments. I can't vote on [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374620/bug-while-upvoting-comments-on-meta#comment633619_374620) comment to help it break the record, sadly.

Comment: @yivi, Let me do that;)

Comment: @yivi: I think this only works if you haven't voted on that comment previously, before the bug happened.

Comment: @Cerbrus: You will probably get a reward for the most upvoted comment ;) 36 upvotes and 16 views so far

Comment: I felt a disturbance in the force. As if a million of votes suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced. :(

Comment: Still can't upvote twice. :$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Same cause as last time: [The road to .NET Core - please help Stack Exchange test EF Core!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316278/the-road-to-net-core-please-help-stack-exchange-test-ef-core)

Fix is building out now.

Comment: It should be fixed in about six minutes once the build is finished.

Comment: Well there goes my opportunity for a 100+ voted comment :D Thanks for the quick response!