# Should a user delete their own question caused by a typo before closure?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

I asked a question whose root cause was a typo in my code... Yeah, unfortunately I'm human.

When someone commented, telling me the correct word, I immediately asked if I should delete the question before any other action was taken.

No one answered me, and of course, close votes quickly reached three.

I felt like it would be a burden for the Stack Overflow system, so I deleted the question just before it reached four close votes. This happened within three minutes, and I had no idea what to do.

Just to be sure, I did the right thing... right?

I told myself... Better make this thing disappear rather than having the close process take care of it.

Comment: The more people interact with your question before you delete it the worse it counts against you with the automatic question ban algorithm. Get rid of 'em quick.

Comment: How could you tell that the fourth close vote was about to arrive? Just curious

Comment: @Don'tPanic I think he just assumed it would since it was a typo question

Comment: see also: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Comment: I don’t get it. Why not just correct the typo instead of deleting the question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Antoine means that the question was asked _because of_ the typo, @ChristiaanWesterbeek. In other words, maybe the asker at first thought they had a problem with an API, but it turned out to just be (something like) a misspelled variable name.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, if it will be of no further use to anyone, you should go ahead and delete it yourself. This should remove it from any review queues, so it won't be put in front of any more reviewers.

Comment: Good, so it IS better, thank you !

Comment: I asume you mean "... before it has received any answers". If it did receive answers, [the answer referenced by @gnat applies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Comment: @smci: Pretty sure typo questions are an exception to that. Unless the answerer has put tremendous effort into providing a comprehensive analysis of the typo, what causes the typo, what can be done to avoid such mistakes, etc, such a question is subject to closure and deletion even if an answer is provided that says nothing more than "you have a typo:" and anyone posting a trivial answer to such a question should not expect their answer to survive for long. There is no reason a question that no longer needs to exist should be held hostage by the mere presence of an answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: right, but I thought that (for the asker) to self-delete a question after it has received an answer triggers abuse detection. I think you're referring to moderators deleting it.

Comment: @smci, I wasn't aware of this, but from Shog9's answer, it looks like that would only be a problem if deleting questions right after an answer is posted is a *pattern* of behavior. Hopefully people aren't posting and deleting strings of typo questions.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378862/3956566). You could either deleted it immediately upon realising the mistake (you can also leave a comment before deleting explaining it's a typo.), or vote to close it as a typo then delete.

Either way preventing others from wasting time answering the question is a good thing. As does removing the post from review queues.

If it has upvoted answers it's another issue, as you cannot self-delete. You can raise a custom mod flag asking for it to be deleted.

Comment: If there are upvoted answers, doesn't that mean other people made the same typo, and thus the question may have value to others?

Comment: @ZevSpitz upvoted answers are independent of whether a question is on topic. If it's a simple typo, the question is off topic.

Comment: @ZevSpitz The upvoted answers often just point out the typo and likely wouldn't be useful. On the other hand  sometimes they provide help on how to debug the issue if the typo is not visible or hard to spot in the question, so sometimes they could be useful. But yeah, if the question doesn't fit, it doesn't matter how good the answers are.