# Deleting dead questions from my account

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have several dead questions on my account; meaning that they all fall into the category of:

- No upvotes or downvotes.
- No answers.
- More than one month old.
- Less than 40 views.

They definitely fall into the <kbd>[tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=9893154)</kbd> category (in my opinion); but I believe the badge is only awarded to new questions and thus not all of them qualified.

---

The questions I would like to recommend for deletion are:

> [Calculate Vertex Position from supplied Position, Rotation, and Scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974203/calculate-vertex-position-from-supplied-position-rotation-and-scale): 2 mo, 36 v
>   [Can I raise an event from base class after overridden method executes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619015/can-i-raise-an-event-from-base-class-after-overridden-method-executes): 1 mo, 32 v
>   [EntityDeploySplit Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032644/entitydeploysplit-error): 6 mo, 25 v
>   [World to Screen (Ignoring Z-Axis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602849/world-to-screen-ignoring-z-axis): 1 mo, 17 v

There are two others that don't completely fit the category defined above since they are just under one month old, but the view counts are incredibly low and they still fit all other descriptions given.

> [Ensure Full Screen Quad is Rendered behind everything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818250/ensure-full-screen-quad-is-rendered-behind-everything-else): 27 d, 19 v

Along with this one which was marked as duplicate due to my lack of knowledge of the technical terms behind boxing and unboxing:

> [Why can't we cast as generic type if the supplied type has implicit conversion available? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964553/why-cant-we-cast-as-generic-type-if-the-supplied-type-has-implicit-conversion-a): 15 d, 30 v

---

Am I able to delete these questions myself? I am worried that if I delete too many of my own questions (even though they meet the criteria above), that my account may be suspended. If not, then can a moderator delete them? If so, how do I put in that request?

**NOTE:** I do not intend to delete any of my questions that have answers, regardless of votes or otherwise since that means someone put forth great effort to help with the issue.

Comment: @usr2564301 I have a few questions that I've answered myself and I've left those alone since they can help future readers with similar issues. Those in particular I haven't come up with a solution.

Comment: @PerpetualJ deleting just because you don't have an answer (especially when you still need an answer) isn't great.  You never know how long it will take to find an answer.  One of my better answers was left 2 years after the question was asked.  At the time it had 2 bad answers, few views, and little voting activity.  But now it is a bit more popular.  So if the question is interesting, don't be afraid to leave it around, someone might solve it eventually

Comment: I have found a dead question in my account which was asked 2 years ago, has 0 votes and 0 answers. I have deleted it on my own. Will it affect my reputation or badge?

Comment: You want to delete these because ....? I'm not seeing what the gain is, here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Jeff Atwood [wrote on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest/97720#97720):

> So long as your self-deleted questions are more than 30 days old at
>   the time of deletion, they no longer count against you.
>
> This is necessary because of a large contingent of abusive users that
>   ask, then delete, and re-ask.

Shog has gone more in detail here on MSO that [deleted posts are mostly irrelevant to the question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/2441442):

> What matters are poorly-received posts. That is, questions that are
>   downvoted, closed, or flagged as inappropriate in some way. These can
>   all result in post bans and also all result in the post being deleted,
>   but saying deletion is to blame for most post bans is akin to saying
>   that hospitals are to blame for most diseases.
>
> The one exception involves deleting a question right after someone
>   posts an answer to it. This (fairly rare!) pattern is seen as so
>   overtly hostile that it does impose a pretty stiff penalty... But
>   that's also a far cry from "self-censoring".

So basically, make sure your questions are good and do not delete questions where you just got an answer for.

Since your questions do not have any downvotes or answers, it is absolute fine to delete them. If you feel that your question could help future readers you should consider to post a self answer instead and refine the question if necessary.

Comment: It does appear that we are limited to 5 per day though.

Comment: Newer reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban/311812#311812  Essentially the same answer though, deletion on its own is relatively irrelavant to the question ban

Comment: I think it's been 60 days instead of 30?

Comment: @PerpetualJ per [rate limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/165773) "5 of a user's own posts can be deleted by them per day". My understanding is this limit was set in order to prevent mass-deletions in cases of [ragequit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171581/165773)

Comment: Can't be more agree with: "So basically, make sure your questions are good and **do not delete questions where you just got an answer for.**" I've just found my recent deleted answer which solved the question :)