# Will having unwillingly deleted questions without votes negatively affect my account?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, post-ban

I was ban-lifted a month ago from Stack Overflow and now when I try asking a question again on Stack Overflow, it seems like I am banned again although I didn't get any downvotes in the meantime. However, it turns out that 2 or 3 questions that had no votes were automatically deleted by the community. Is this the reason why I got banned again? I am quite lost in how to lift my ban again. I tried my best to improve my questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think it should. Question bans ignore deletion IIRC. But then again, there might be more details behind the algorithm than we know of (or I just missed some details behind it). Sounds weird though, but a mod might be able to tell you more

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/54822152) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/54733157) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/54677056) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/54576815) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/54555649) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/54392181) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/54383493) [8](//stackoverflow.com/q/53466024) [9](//stackoverflow.com/q/53436812) [10](//stackoverflow.com/q/53362393)

Comment: [11](//stackoverflow.com/q/53152356) [12](//stackoverflow.com/q/53132656) [13](//stackoverflow.com/q/53128850) [14](//stackoverflow.com/q/53128702) [15](//stackoverflow.com/q/51202205) [16](//stackoverflow.com/q/50257254) [17](//stackoverflow.com/q/49966664) [18](//stackoverflow.com/q/47201710) [19](//stackoverflow.com/q/46615338) [20](//stackoverflow.com/q/46292882))

Comment: @Zoe IIRC It ignores the deletion itself, but the deleted questions do still count

Comment: @Nick yeah, that's what I meant ^^" I specifically meant that the system doesn't care if the question is deleted or not, and counts it towards a potential asking ban anyway.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I understand that I deleted a few questions in the past.  However, I haven't deleted any questions on my own in recent days.

Comment: You are way below the threshold: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/885476/am-i-quality-banned-for-questions?negdel=12&closedel=8&deleted=20&UserId=8196858 a couple of deleted questions more or less is not going to cut it I'm afraid. You need to have a bit of luck with asking an awesome question in 6 months.

Comment: @rene thank you for letting me know! Didn't know there was a formula for it!

Comment: Keep in mind the exact formula is secret but this is the best rough estimate we can get based on available data. See it as a ballpark figure, not an exact science.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is: Go spend time (you have plenty of it) on [the checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and other resources like [this external site](https://idownvotedbecau.se/) to get a good idea what an excellent question should look like. Then go over your deleted, zero scored but not closed questions and see which edit you can make to one of them to turn them into an excellent question. Make that edit then flag for a mod to ask for undeletion. Rinse and repeat every 6 to 8 days. Edits do help. Use it,

Comment: Alternatively: turn your attention to editing other users post or even tag wikis. That does earn you a bit of reputation (+2) for each accepted edit. It brings lots of posts in front of your eyes and that will help you determine which posts are good and which ones don't go well. Use that knowledge and apply it to your deleted posts. You have 6 months if nothing changes. Use that time effectively. There is no rush. Doing things wrong today will only put you farther back. Take your time.

Comment: also consider reviewing in the queues but make sure you do it right or you end-up like this user: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396262/2-week-ban-for-incorrect-triage. All the duplicates on that question are good study material.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [big meta guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/6471538) on post bans, "Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions less than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question." According to the [Help Center documentation on the roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), only *closed* questions are subject to automatic deletion before the end of 30 days. This indicates that the questions probably did not impact your ban unless they had been closed.

In addition, keep in mind that the question ban (see my first link) allows a 'free' question every six months *despite* the ban. This may be what you experienced - you may have never actually been unbanned, with your most recent six-month question not good enough to lift you out of the ban.

Comment: "**Deleted posts are mostly irrelevant to the question ban.** If someone tells you otherwise, tell them they're wrong; if you see a meta post that says otherwise, edit it. 

What matters are *poorly-received* posts..." ([Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601))