# How old can a question get before it's considered "dead"?

Tags: discussion, bounty, old-questions

I've noticed that on Stack Overflow, most questions get answered pretty quickly (<30 minutes for the first answer, with more answers coming in over the course of the next day or so). But if a question doesn't get answered immediately, it often doesn't get answered at all unless a bounty is placed.

After what period of time would you personally "write off" a question as unlikely to get answered in the future? If any.

As @rene pointed out, I mean "dead" as in "unlikely to be answered" and not "dead" as in "deleted" or "should be deleted".

Comment: let me link to the roomba: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba as that one also knows the concept of "dead" questions You might want to make clear it is not about that "dead"

Comment: I've seen questions get their first answer years after they were posted. It's not common, but it happens. I wouldn't consider a question truly dead unless it becomes unanswerable in some way (e.g. it's about an API that no longer exists or something like that).

Comment: possibly related: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, after two days if there's no answer posted, the chances to get answer later are pretty small.

It's not set in stone, e.g. in [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377618/web-service-throwing-lots-of-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receive-when-co) I got a quick answer which was not useful, and useful answer arrived only after five days - but generally speaking, you're correct, and unless a bounty is placed, or meaningful edit is done, the question will be buried away, and sometimes automatically deleted as mentioned in the comment by @rene.

Anyhow, I'd advise against acting upon it, i.e. deleting such questions. Better leave them be, and hope for the best - I've seen cases of questions getting a good answer months and years after being posted, there are badges and hats (during winter bash) for that.

Comment: But [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779546) *[does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55943113)* [happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797910/how-can-i-debug-c-in-geany/60922799#60922799) occasionally (real answers, not just hints). Not everybody is focused on new questions. Some of the more challenging questions are to be found among questions that haven't *really* been answered (often encountered in search engine hits). [Off-site example](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/75525).

Answer (score 6):

The only difference between a question that you've "written off" and one that you haven't is your expectation.

If the question is important to you and you need help but haven't gotten any, consider editing the question to better explain the problem, provide more information, etc. If you put effort into asking your question, making it clear, and providing enough information, it's much more likely that someone will put some effort into answering.

Questions that languish with no answers are often the ones that even the OP doesn't really care enough about to spend time on.

Comment: Editing your question in a significant way will increase its visibility - the system will put it on the front page. It may be obvious, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5):

There's no single limit. It is largely topic- and difficulty-dependent. The more obscure the technology and the more difficult the question, the longer it typically takes to answer, so expectations should follow suit. Non-difficult questions in popular technologies (e.g. filtering and reducing a JavaScript array of objects or selecting rows from a Pandas dataframe) that aren't answered in a few hours could be considered inactive. The question is *likely* unclear, doesn't show an attempt or needs minimization or it'd have been answered, but in many cases was not so egregiously off-topic to warrant instant closures.

But questions about, say, constraint solvers or a technology like working with a parser generator, web GL, or even JS canvas might wait a few days for the few people who watch the tag pull up their list of unanswered questions and take a crack at it. Expecting such questions to be answered within 30 minutes is unrealistic.

There are some tags, like [turtle-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turtle-graphics) that have one person who will post some sort of answer within a couple of days. If you click on 4-5 [turtle-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turtle-graphics) questions with answers, I guarantee you'll figure out who the user I'm talking about is (or cheat and look at [top users for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/turtle-graphics/topusers)). If this person decided to suddenly stop answering, I speculate that there would be droves of unanswered questions in the tag, which most users avoid. Questions in this tag have a turnaround of about a day, commensurate with the schedule of a single user. Although in many cases less extreme as [turtle-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turtle-graphics), there are strange oddities to many tags that make the turnaround time estimates very particular and hard to apply a one-size-fits-all model to.

For questions that are "dead", some are well-asked but in an obscure tag or are difficult to answer. Others are poor quality, but not enough people looked at it to cast close votes.

Another factor that could go into whether a question is dead is the asker's reputation, although this is usually correlated with the "difficulty" metric I propose above. It's common for high-rep users to ask questions that aren't easily answered, aren't closed and need to sit and gather upvotes for a domain expert to wander along and help them out. It's a mistake to consider such questions dead for a good while, if ever, while similar questions from low-rep users are more likely to be considered dead sooner.

Luck and random noise are also involved.