# I have been post banned and I would appreciate some help improving some of my questions

Tags: support, post-ban

I have been banned from posting to Stack Overflow after posting this question: [Adding CORS headers to my NodeJS ExpressJS API but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222007/adding-cors-headers-to-my-nodejs-expressjs-api-but-not-working)

I am not really sure why I was downvoted twice, and I actually got an answer that solved my problem. So I am not sure whether I should try to improve the question or leave it. I am actually afraid of making it worse.

I also started deleting older questions that had no answers and that I thought were obsolete and polluting the website, but I quickly un-deleted them when I saw that deleting questions can actually contribute to being banned.

I attempted to improve some 0- and negative-score questions, but to be honest, I don't know what to improve sometimes. I have always put a lot of time and effort to write questions as clear as possible.

I have 3 questions that were noted as [duplicate], and a couple of `python` questions that were not appreciated for reasons that I don't get. This probably contributed to the ban.

I read that I could get help here to reinstate my Stackoverflow account. I am not sure exactly what do to, and I am afraid to make it worse.

Comment: For that specific question, if I had to guess, looks like the downvotes came when the error message hadn't been stated, making it a guessing game or perhaps even an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's still a lingering close vote asking for debugging detail, but the fact that it's not closed means that the question is probably clear now (whether there's a dupe on somewhere else or not is another case though).

Comment: *"I am not really sure why I was downvoted twice"* - you weren't. We vote on content, not people. I agree that the question is not really downvote worthy, but I don't dictate how other people should vote. And keep this in mind: your problem is not the two downvotes. Your problem is the *zero upvotes*. That is the bigger sign that something is wrong. I wholeheartedly disagree with your answer acceptance too. It only does a library recommendation without any further explanation, it does not explain to you or anyone else what was wrong with your manual attempt. Not very useful.

Comment: related: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601) "Whether a post was deleted is mostly irrelevant to the question ban..."

Comment: Thank you for your replies, they are very much appreciated.
@Andrew T I realise forgetting to include the error message is not helpful and this is the first time I write a question and forget the error message. This had been repaired before the ban though.

Comment: @Gimby I understand people are not downvoting me :)
Yes, there is obviously something wrong with my question(s). But I don't know how to fix that. For this particular question I had already added the missing error message before the ban. What else is wrong? Would people downvote the question because I accepted this particular reply? It actually solved a problem I had been working on for ages. I thought it would genuinely help others.

Comment: Oh, the answer that I had selected suddenly disappeared. Seriously, what's going on lol

Comment: [That answer](https://cln.sh/RWCzV0) was a "link-only" answer. Those are not considered answers for the purpose of the site. [It was flagged as a "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) and deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Great news: The ban has been lifted! Thank you so much for your help!
I learned a valuable lesson today. I will be EXTRA careful next time I write a question.

Comment: Nope, it's gone again. I have no idea what's going on lol

Comment: @OlivierGirardot - If you are talking about the answer, it was likely deleted, due to the fact it didn't meet the quality expectations of the community.  If it only contained a linked that would be one reason.  Questions bans do not happen due to a single bad question.  They only happen after a continued pattern of asking questions that are not well received.  You are shown a warning of that fact, before each and every question, once you got to the point where you were eligible to see the warning.

Comment: @Security Hound
I am not 100% sure there was a link. But if there was, there was also an explanation. And I remember the explanation because it solved my problem. And it was exactly the kind of simple and straight forward solution that I was looking for. The author was bringing to my attention the existence of an npm package and showing me how to install it. It worked perfectly and solved my problem.
But anyway, I respect the choice to remove it, to whoever did that. I just fail to understand how my question is more helpful now, without any reply at all.

Comment: And I understand, that there are several questions that caused the ban. But I am here because I am not sure what I did wrong and looking for help to improve the questions that are problematic.
This one for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267137/python-user-input-as-a-function-argument-not-working-typeerror-str-object-i

Comment: That one is a too basic error to improve anyrhing upon.

Comment: Searching for the error you received '"str' object is not callable" provided me numerous detailed explanations for the error.  Seems like a classic case of not doing enough research effort before asking a question.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/63158208) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/62638666)

Comment: It was definitely a link only answer, in its entirety it read *"I would highly suggest you use the following NPM package for CORS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors"*, they didn't actually explain anything or show you how to install (or use) it. These kinds of answers are not considered useful per e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731. Compare to e.g. http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html (the first result when you search Google for "Express CORS") with installation guidance and examples.

Comment: Ah Ok my bad... but how did you retrieve that answer? I couldn't find it anywhere...
I am bookmarking the link though, it did save my life :)

Comment: That's not your fault, it's on the answerer! Users with more than 10k rep can view deleted posts, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools. Also @yivi [posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401935/i-have-been-banned-and-i-would-appreciate-some-help-improving-some-of-my-questio#comment801353_401935) a screenshot of it.

Comment: @Olivier Also, to clear up anything about accepting answers, that choice is *always* up to you as the asker. ["The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/776523) Others won't always agree, and may sometimes disagree with your choice rather strongly, but the choice is yours all the same. The community gets to decide what's best by voting, but the asker gets to freely accept whatever they so choose, regardless.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zcoop98 and jonrsharpe all the others for your tremendous help. I think the ban has been lifted again, I am very much relieved. I will be extra careful when asking a question from now on, and I will remember all the advice that you guys gave me here. Thanks again, this is a great community!

Comment: Your newest question is also no good, you have a huge amount of text and then the actual question finally at the end is only `Is there a way this approach could work, or should I look for a different approach, or maybe a even a different framework?` - as a question this is too broad, opinion based, and asking for recommendations.  That's 3 different ways in which your question is specifically not allowed.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/64320005/325727. Looks like you havent learnt anything about how to ask after all.

Comment: @JK yeah I realise that. I got caught up with my desire to solve my problem selfishly, and I didn't think of how this question could be relevant and useful to the others. I deleted the question, as I think it was polluting.