How can I improve my questions if the majority of them are almost 10 years old?
To give some context, I have been given a question ban, and I've been told to edit my questions. The issue however is that the majority of my questions are over 8 years old. I would've written these when I was 12/13 years old, and now looking back at these questions, I'm not too sure what I was looking for, nor do I fully understand a lot of the code, as I've moved away from these languages.
Deleting questions works against the ban from what I've read, and realistically I believe that some of these questions should be deleted. My question is, what am I supposed to do when I'm unfamiliar with the languages within my old questions, and how can I go about improving them? This question suggests contacting support, however the comments, and the support page conflict with this answer.

you can ask one question every six months. If those are all stellar questions you'll eventually get out of the ban.

The undeleted questions I see on your account, both old and new, are pretty well received. To fall into this, as far as we understand the private algorithm, would require quite a few poorly received deleted questions. Perhaps some of those are newer? Generally, people don't suddenly get Q-banned because of old questions, because they'd have to attract new votes.

@KarlKnechtel 8 deleted questions, 1 from 2021, the rest from 2015

Hmm, a bit strange, then. I guess another possibility is that the Q-ban has been in place since 2021 and gone unnoticed until a recent attempt to ask more than one question... ?

@KarlKnechtel this would be the case I assume. I haven't really made much use of the platform other than to find similar questions. I've finally ran into the scenario where I have a question which hasn't been answered, which led me to find out I've been question banned.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump Regarding those deleted questions, would undeleting some of these and making edits potentially help to lift the ban? Even looking at these, some are completely unsalvagable, but it could be easier than the remaining questions I have open.

If you cannot improve your decade old questions, then your only choice, is to ask better questions once every 6 months.  You were warned before asking your last question, before the question ban, that you were close to becoming question banned.  So, this didn't necessarily come out of the blue. Deleting questions only causes the threshold to get out of a question ban harder to achieve since those questions cannot be upvoted. You might have been unaware that question bans existed. Does not change the fact you were unaware your questions were not being well received.

Any chance the "minimal reproducible example" in your most recent question could be made more minimal?

@SecurityHound If the warning was received in 2021 as it seems like it may have been, I can hardly fault OP for forgetting about it. If it was received this June, well, that question is at +1.

@SecurityHound if you look at some of the deleted questions, you can see that their deletion was not recent, most of these were deleted 8 years ago. Considering that the account hasn't been used up until recently, you're hardly expecting me to remember anything from this time, let alone a warning that I may have gotten? Undeleting these questions would not be beneficial, they were questions which provided no benefit to visiting users.

@RowanHarley - I cannot see deleted questions. So I can't judge if those questions can be salvaged. I of course am aware of every question I have asked but that might be because I don't ask a ton of questions.

@RowanHarley "would undeleting some of these and making edits potentially help to lift the ban?" Yes, deletion itself counts against you IIRC so undeleting would help there, but they can't be voted on while deleted so if you want them to improve in score they'd need to be undeleted anyway. Do note that you can edit the questions before undeleting them; that is recommended so that, as soon as they're undeleted, they're "worthy" of being upvoted (as much as possible, anyway. Some questions can't be salvaged).

Did you delete any questions that had answers already?

@MWB - It should not matter asking a question then deleting the question is not positive behavior that should be avoided at all costs.

@SecurityHound Does SO say so anywhere? I always assumed it was fine, as long as the question has no answers.

@MWB - Deleted question most definitely count against your ability to ask new questions. There isn’t any documentation on the question ban algorithm

@SecurityHound "Deleted question most definitely count against your ability to ask new questions." Where do you get this information? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812

"and I've been told to edit my questions" - no what you've been told is that this may help, but there are no guarantees at this point. It is hard to get the privilege of asking questions back. Unfortunately things you've done in the past don't have a diminishing return, they count just as hard today as they did back then. I really don't like that, but it works the same for everyone I'm afraid. It sucks but it's fair.

I would advise contacting support regardless of what the support page says. You have been a user visiting this platform for years. Your track record is invalidating the assumption behind the ban that your behaviour is not aligned with how the platform is intended to be used.

Fixing up decade old questions is unlikely to be rewarded with enough upvotes on them to lift the ban. Honestly, you'd be lucky to get any votes from it. Either be willing to spend literal years of posting two good questions a year (and hoping nobody in a bad mood gives them a random drive by down vote ), or write off SO and find some other platform to ask questions on.

@Shawn Wouldn't OP be better off making a new account than looking for "some other platform"? IMHO the quality of answers on SO is better than it is on the competition. Or would making a new account be against SO policy? I would think doing so wouldn't be allowed if the ban was due to abuse, but it seems in this case the ban is a "false positive" from the algorithm and OP deserves another chance. After all, if I had been on SO at 12-13yo I doubt my questions would have been high quality, or made much sense today.

@MathRules using another account to bypass post bans isn't allowed and would result in the other account being deleted / merged with the current one.

@RobertLongson I am someone who has gotten question banned before but got out of it. I'll just point out that this is an exaggeration. I got out of it simply by editing and changing my existing questions and from the upvotes on them. I don't think it's necessary to ask a new question after the 6 month mark because if you have enough questions and if they are salvagable, then editing them might help you out of it. If not, then 1 or 2 "6th-month" questions with greater than 0 upvotes should be sufficient.

@SpaceTrucker I'm not so sure of that. It seems like OP has scarcely used the site since an initial flurry of activity that ended up in the ban. (Did this system exist in 2015?)

To an add an update to the above, after reaching out to support, they were able to remove the question ban, so thank you @SpaceTrucker for that.  Given the age of the questions, and the fact that recent posts were not negatively received, they were happy to reset the ban. With that being said, it should raise questions about the way in which question bans work. Maybe questions should be time-weighted, such that older questions have less of an affect on a question ban.

@RowanHarley From what I understand they don't have a mechanism to just remove the question ban, you did receive upvotes on some of your questions after this Meta post so either you got out of the question ban automatically due to those or the other possibility is that staff helped you get out of the ban by dissociating (there's little chance of them doing this without you explicitly requesting it) you from some negatively scored questions that were weighing towards your ban.

@MathRules you have to wonder why the quality is higher on Stack Overflow... it's because it is strictly curated and has content protection mechanisms like revoking privileges from people and outright banning them... and making sure they stay that way.  Keyword: strict. No ifs, ands or buts. You can always search for answers, the primary use of this site. Not being able to post questions specifically on Stack Overflow is not as crippling as people want to make it seem.

@AbdulAzizBarkat They did help me get out of the ban by dissociating. I assume this was the only way in which the ban could be removed in my case, as most questions I had asked in those early years were pretty poorly recieved.
